# How to convert simple string into an int in Python (pyramid)

Tags: python, string, integer, pyramid

Trying to convert friend id "5" into a number in Python

When I try to convert this string into a number I get an error:

```
[Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WhoAt/env/www/www/views/contacts/contacts.py line:63]
un_friend()
     ->contact = int(friend)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"5"'
```

Python

```
## friend is "5" str
friend = self.request.body
## Tried:
contact = int(friend)
## and just:
int(friend)
```

I found the code I tried above [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979077/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-python). Neither work and both cause the error above.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to have to create a new def just to convert this, isn't there a way to do this with a few characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"5"` is in double quotes, [strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) them:

```
int(friend.strip('"'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = '"5"'
>>> int(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"5"'
>>> int(s.strip('"'))
5
```

Comment: Doing `friend.strip()` could get you in trouble. Make sure you are aware of the bounds on the friendship.

Comment: Or use `int(eval(s))`. But can be dangerous too. If you have mixed str/int, `int(eval(str(s)))`.

Comment: Thanks! I come from javascript and "" mean's a string, still very newb at Python :)

Comment: `""` and `''` mean string in Python as well, but just like in JavaScript if you nest them `'""'` or `"''"`, you get a string with quotes inside it. In either language, `'"5"' != "5"`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your string is `"5"` instead of `5`, notice the double quote.