# What is wrong with my areas problems code in python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
j = True
  while j == True:

area = raw_input("Elije la figura geometrica para calcular su area 
 \nCuadrado=1 \nTriangulo=2 \nCirculo=3\n")

if area == 1 :
 acuadrado()
```

the problem is in the area.It is something in the syntax?

Comment: Your indentation is soo off

Comment: Fix question formating, provide traceback, explain what you are trying to do and what you are struggling with and provide full code. Without that nobody can help you. **and please check that [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` in python2.x returns a "string" representation of the users input. Your wanting to do numerical comparison on the input, so you'll want to cast the `area` variable to an integer (`int`) before performing the comparison. Something like the following:

```
area = int(raw_input("Elije la figura geometrica..")
```

or

```
area = raw_input("Elije ...")
area = int(area)
```

then you can compare `int` values:

```
if area == 1 :
        acuadrado()
```

etc...

altogether something like this might help you get along:

```
def acuadrado():
    print 'acuadrado'

def atriangulo():
    print 'atriangulo'

def acirculo():
    print 'acirculo'


j = True

while j == True:

    area = raw_input("Elije la figura geometrica para calcular su area \nCuadrado=1 \nTriangulo=2 \nCirculo=3\n")

    area = int(area)

    if area == 1 :
        acuadrado()
    elif area == 2:
        atriangulo()
    elif area == 3:
        acirculo()
    else:
        print 'nada'
        j = False
```

Also see [How can I convert a string to an int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979077/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-python)

Hope that helps.