# Why do I keep getting an error? (I'm new so if it is obvious I'm sorry)

Tags: python, type-conversion

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

```
vector1x = int(point1x - observerpointx)
vector1y = int(point1y - observerpointy)
vector1z = int(point1z - observerpointz)
vector2x = int(point2x - observerpointx)
vector2y = int(point2y - observerpointy)
vector2z = int(point2z - observerpointz)`
```

Comment: `vector1x = int(point1x) - int(observerpointx)`. Same for others (probably).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to an int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979077/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, we can not do `str` - `str`. So, we need to convert them to `int`.

e.g. `vector1x = int(point1x) - int(observerpointx)`.