# Binary search program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def bsearch(s, e, first, last):
    print(first, last)
    if (last - first) < 2:
        return s[first] == e or s[last] == e
    mid = first + (last - first) / 2
    if s[mid] == e: return True
    if s[mid] > e: return bsearch(s, e, first, mid - 1)
    return bsearch(s, e, mid + 1, last)

def search1(s,e):
    print(bsearch(s, e, 0, len(s)-1))
    print('Search complete')

def testSearch():
    s = range(0, 1000000)
    input('binary,-1')
    print(search1(s, -1))
```

It's binary search algorithm. I have two questions.

Question 1:
Why is `first` necessary in the following line?

```
mid = first + (last - first) / 2
```

Question 2:
I can't run the result, when I ran the program.
The error message is:

```
range indices must be integers or slices, not float.
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: What did you find when you googled 'python 3 float',  'python 3 range function', and your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Question 2:

The error message "range indices must be integers or slices, not float" tells you that you are trying to slice (get a part of a list-like collection, e.g. with `some_list[5:]`) using float, not int. To be more precise, your `mid` is `5.0`, not `5`.

In Python 3 the default division is floating division (unlike Python 2). To get the integer division you need to use double slash operator:

```
mid = first + (last - first) // 2
```

Regarding Question 1: mid is the middle element. It is elementary equation to get the middle element, but maybe you are confused because you expected the other, equivalent equation; it can be calculated as

```
mid = first + (last - first) // 2
```

or:

```
mid = (first + last) // 2
```

The equation could be different if you were using an implementation which creates copies of list `s` at each recursive call. The implementation you provided works "in-place" so it needs the absolute coordinates.

EDIT: as pointed by @philipxy in comments, you could easily find what was causing the slice-related error, searching for your error message + "division".

I just tested this and the first Google result points to [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355816/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-float); as this is exactly the same problem as yours (binary search), this question could be flagged as duplicate and closed if not your second question contained herein. In fact some more experienced users still may decide do flag it as a duplicate.