# How to calculate difference between two dates in weeks in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates in "weeks of year". I can get the datetime object and get the days etc but not week numbers. I can't, of course, subtract dates because weekends can't be ensured with that.

I tried getting the week number using `d1.isocalendar()[1]` and subtracting `d2.isocalendar()[1]` but the issue is that `isocalendar()[1]` returns `December 31, 2012` as week 1 (which supposedly is correct) but that means my logic cannot span over this date.

For reference, here's my complete code:

```
def week_no(self):
    ents = self.course.courselogentry_set.all().order_by('lecture_date')
    l_no = 1
    for e in ents:
        if l_no == 1: 
             starting_week_of_year = e.lecture_date.isocalendar()[1] # get week of year
             initial_year = e.lecture_date.year   
        if e == self: 
            this_year = e.lecture_date.year
            offset_week = (this_year - initial_year) * 52
            w_no = e.lecture_date.isocalendar()[1] - starting_week_of_year + 1 + offset_week
            break 
        l_no += 1
    return w_no
```

With this code, the lecture on Dec 31, 2012 ends up being -35.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

How about calculating the difference in weeks between the **Mondays** within weeks of respective dates? In the following code, `monday1` is the Monday on or before `d1` (the same week):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

monday1 = (d1 - timedelta(days=d1.weekday()))
monday2 = (d2 - timedelta(days=d2.weekday()))

print 'Weeks:', (monday2 - monday1).days / 7
```

Returns **0** if both dates fall withing one week, **1** if on two consecutive weeks, etc.

Comment: Can you just elaborate your code by explaining it, specially on the `monday1` and `monday2` calculations.

Comment: Works perfectly, spans across years and weeks. Very concise too. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I get an error with `days()` : `(Pdb) (monday2 - monday1).days()
*** TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
(Pdb) (monday2 - monday1).days
77`

Comment: Guess I'm a bit late here..
Shouldn't the last line be:
print (monday2 - monday1).days/7 instead of
print (monday2 - monday1).days()/7

Comment: Agreed, `timedelta.days` as an attribute, not a method. Unlike `total_seconds()` which is a method.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answer is simply WRONG, because timedelta.days is an attribute rather than a method. Why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: I just edited the answer so that "days" is used instead of "days()". So the last few comments will no longer be relevant (assuming the edit is accepted). I added 'Weeks:' only because edits have to change at least 6 characters.

Comment: Suppose, we have 3 epochs ```s = 1326777816; s1 = 1431480091; s2 = 1431434968```. Actually, ```s1``` and ```s2``` are in the same week but using the function above there are 172 weeks between ```s1``` and ```s``` while 173 weeks between ```s2``` and ```s```. It is very strange because ```s2 < s1``` so the number of week should be smaller. 

Noted: I convert epoch to ```datetime ``` by ```datetime.fromtimestamp(s)``` before  applying the function.

I think the answer of [Rashmi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14191912/3138459) is more correct.

Comment: This answer is not correct, what to do with both monday's hours, minutes, etc? To get the correct answer the both dates should have hours and minutes and seconds to be reset to zero, otherwise will get negative values in some cases

Comment: It is not necessary and distracting to zero d1 and d2 back their previous Mondays at midnight. (d2 - d1).days/7  is all that is needed. Integer division by the 7 means that decimal weeks are chopped off - whala - you get only what you wanted the whole weeks.

Comment: In my opinion it shoud be: (monday2.date() - monday1.date()).days / 7
instead of (monday2 - monday1).days / 7. This gives good result (1 instead of 0) for these two dates:
1970-01-18 15:12:28
1970-01-19 05:05:48

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, d1 and d2 are the two dates, right? What format should the dates be in?

Comment: Same thing but a bit more concise: `weeks = ((d2 - d1).days + d1.weekday() - d2.weekday()) // 7`

Answer (score 48):

You may want to refer the Python CookBook (2005 edition) Recipe 3.3. The following code snippet is from the cookbook, does what you require.

```
from dateutil import rrule
import datetime
def weeks_between(start_date, end_date):
    weeks = rrule.rrule(rrule.WEEKLY, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date)
    return weeks.count()
```

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tested this out but even it works, I think eumiro's solution is more elegant. +1 though for an alternative :)

Answer (score 28):

This is a very simple solution with less coding everyone would understand.

```
from datetime import date

d1 = date(year, month, day)
d2 = date(year, month, day)
result = (d1-d2).days//7
```

Comment: Works tested (date(2018, 5, 3) - date(2017, 12, 25)).days/7 and verified https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=25&m1=12&y1=2017&d2=3&m2=5&y2=2018

Comment: Good, it works for you, should be this (date(2018, 5, 3) - date(2017, 12, 25)).days//7

Comment: Nice. I missed the floor division. The floor operator is better! I was relying on python 2's default integer division which behaves the same as // but that is not true in python 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-2-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Comment: This solution doesn't give the difference in calendar weeks. For example, if d1 is a Friday and d2 is Tuesday of the following week, there are 4 days between the two dates which would result in 0 weeks but the answer should be 1 calendar week.

Answer (score 4):

The solution above has a bug (I can't add a comment due to low reputation). It doesn't account for hour differences.

```
# This code has a bug.
monday1 = (d1 - timedelta(days=d1.weekday()))
monday2 = (d2 - timedelta(days=d2.weekday()))
```

Counter example of 2 dates more than a week apart:

```
Timestamp1: 1490208193270795 (22 Mar 2017 18:43:13 GMT)
Monday1: 20 Mar 2017 18:43:13 GMT

Timestamp2: 1489528488744290 (14 Mar 2017 21:54:48 GMT)
Monday2: 13 Mar 2017 21:54:48 GMT
```

Using that code it returns 0 as week diff when it should be 1. Need to zero out the hours/minutes/seconds as well.

Answer (score 2):

To determine how many weeks are spanned by two dates. eg From 3rd Oct to 13th Oct

```
    October 2015
Mo     5 12 19 26
Tu     6 13 20 27
We     7 14 21 28
Th  1  8 15 22 29
Fr  2  9 16 23 30
Sa  3 10 17 24 31
Su  4 11 18 25
```

Code:

```
    import math, datetime

    start_date = datetime.date(2015, 10, 3)
    start_date_monday = (start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=start_date.weekday()))
    end_date = datetime.date(2015, 10, 13)
    num_of_weeks = math.ceil((end_date - start_date_monday).days / 7.0)
```

Equals 3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Edited Best Answer

```
from datetime import timedelta
monday1 = (d1 - timedelta(days=d1.weekday()))
monday2 = (d2 - timedelta(days=d2.weekday()))
diff = monday2 - monday1
noWeeks = (diff.days / 7)  + math.ceil(diff.seconds/86400)
print('Weeks:', noWeeks)`
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer and what is the improvement?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit vague on what 'difference in weeks' means exactly.  Is 6 days difference one week  or zero ? Is eight days difference one week or two ?

In any case, why can't you simply find the difference in another unit (seconds or days) and divide by the appropriate amount, with your prefered rounding for weeks?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was actually talking about difference in "week of year". So, it's not sufficient to say "6 days". If first day is monday, second is thursday, week difference is 0 but if one is saturday and two is sunday, week difference is 1.