# use of // in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am new in python programming. I have come to piece of program in which

```
if (pos.x//1,pos.y//1) not in self.cleaned:
     self.cleaned.append((pos.x//1,pos.y//1))
```

is used. It might be silly of me. But can anyone please tell me what the code means. And please tell me the function of "//".

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Answer (score 8):

It is the explicit floor division operator.

```
5 // 2 # 2
```

In Python 2.x and below the `/` would do integer division if both of the operands were integers and would do floating point division if at least one argument was a float.

In Python 3.x this was changed, and the `/` operator does floating-point division and the `//` operator does floor division.

References:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Answer (score 7):

`a // b` is [floor division](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). It's basically `floor(a / b)`, but it preserves the number type.

Answer (score 3):

The `/` operator does a *floating-point division*, the `//` operator does *integer division*.

For example:

```
>>> 10/4   #will be 2.5
>>> 10//4  #will be 2
```

Note that this is from python 3.

In python 2. if you try it, you'll get:

```
>>> 10/4     #will be 2
>>> 10.0/4   #will be 2.5
```