# What does "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" mean when using range?

Tags: python, typeerror

I don't understand why I can't use my variable `c`.

code:

```
from turtle import *

speed(0)
hideturtle()
c = 450

def grid(x,y,a):
    seth(0)
    pu()
    goto(x,y)
    pd()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(a)
        rt(90)
    for i in range(c/10):
        seth(0)
        forward(10)
        rt(90)
        forward(c)
        backward(c)
    for i in range(c/10):
        seth(0)
        rt(90)
        forward(10)
        rt(90)
        forward(c)
        backward(c)
    pu()
    goto(a+10,0)
    write("x")
    goto(0,a+10)
    write("y")
    pd()

grid(0,0,c)
grid(-c,0,c)
grid(-c,c,c)
grid(0,c,c)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nick\Desktop\gridv2.py", line 35, in <module>
    grid(0,0,c)
  File "C:\Users\nick\Desktop\gridv2.py", line 15, in grid
    for i in range(c/10):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In:

```
for i in range(c/10):
```

You're creating a float as a result - to fix this use the int division operator:

```
for i in range(c // 10):
```

Comment: This error can occur when migrating from python 2.X to python 3.X

Answer (score 32):

`range()` can only work with integers, but dividing with the `/` operator always results in a float value:

```
>>> 450 / 10
45.0
>>> range(450 / 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Make the value an integer again:

```
for i in range(int(c / 10)):
```

or use the `//` floor division operator:

```
for i in range(c // 10):
```

Answer (score 13):

As shown below, `range` only supports integers:

```
>>> range(15.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
>>> range(15)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>>
```

However, `c/10` is a float because `/` always returns a float.

Before you put it in `range`, you need to make `c/10` an integer.  This can be done by putting it in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int):

```
range(int(c/10))
```

or by using [`//`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division), which returns an integer:

```
range(c//10)
```

Answer (score 10):

It is also possible to fix this with `np.arange()` which works for float numbers, instead of range:

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.arange(c/10):
```