# Python Error: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I am trying to build this tax calculator and keep receiving this error:

> 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

The problem seems to be my `range` line, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
class taxCalc:
   def __init__(self):
      self.brackets_single = {(0,10000):0.15, (10000,45000):.18, (45000,72000):.23, (72000, sys.maxsize):.38}   
      self.brackets_joint = {(0,20000):0.15, (20000,90000):.18, (90000,144000):.23, (144000, sys.maxsize):.38}

   def taxcal(self, income, fil_stat, depen, stdeduc):
      if stdeduc == 'TRUE':            
          if fil_stat == 'single':
              agincome = income - 1000
          elif fil_stat == 'joint':
              agincome = income - 2000
      else: agincome = income


      if depen == 1:
          agincome -= 1000
      elif depen == 2:
          agincome -= 2000
      else:
          agincome = income


      PEP = .02
      if agincome >= 45000 :
          amount = agincome - 45000
          amount /= 1000
          amount *= PEP
          amount *= (1000*depen)
          if 1000*depen - amount > 0:
              agincome += amount
          else: 
              agincome += (1000*depen)

      else: agincome = agincome

      tax = 0
      if fil_stat == 'single':
         for bracket in self.brackets_single:
                     if agincome > bracket[0]:
                         for _ in range(bracket[0], min(agincome, bracket[1])):              
                             tax += self.brackets_single[bracket] 

      elif fil_stat == 'joint':
         for bracket in self.brackets_joint:
                     if agincome > bracket[0]:
                         for _ in range(bracket[0], min(agincome, bracket[1])):
                              tax += self.brackets_joint[bracket] 

      return tax


mytest=taxCalc()          
print(mytest.taxcal(75000, 'single', 1, 'TRUE')), format(round(mytest.taxcal(75000, 'single', 1, 'TRUE'),2))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824721/i-keep-getting-this-error-for-my-simple-python-program-typeerror-float-obje?rq=1

Comment: `agincome` is probably a float, which you can't use in `range`. Try `int(agincome)`.

Comment: Great that works. Thanks!