# Why math.ceil() give different answers

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python. I was trying to solve a matrix problem in which I have to use exit condition in loop for example if column and row of matrix is 3 or 4 then i want to run the loop 2 times and if col and row is 5 or 6 then it run 3 times.

```
>>> math.ceil(1.5)
2.0
>>> i=3
>>> math.ceil(i/2)
1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `3 / 2` isn't `1.5` in Python 2, [it's `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division). Do `from __future__ import division` and then it'll be what you expect.

Comment: why it so ?What is reason behind this?

Comment: @vj1207 [Here is an explanation](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/03/problem-with-integer-division.html) by Guido.

Answer (score 0):

try this first:

```
i=3/2
print i
j=float(3)/2
print j
print math.ceil(j)
```

you should see

```
1
1.5
2.0
```

the way python deals with integer division is taking the lower bound.

Reference:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html

Comment: Correct. Note the **lower** part. Integer division in Python rounds towards -infinite for negative values, **not** towards 0.