# Can I keep decimal precision while using integer division in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I divide 2/3 I get 0.66666666, when I do 2//3 I get 0.

Is there any way to compute integer division while still keeping the decimal points?

Edit: looks like I may have confused a lot of you, my bad.  So what my professor told me that since standard division(2/3) will only return 0.666666666666 up to 203 digits, it is not useful when I want to do computations that requires more than 203 digits after the decimal point. I am wondering if there is a way to do 2//3 (which will return 0) but somehow still get the .6666 in the end

Comment: Why the first method doesn't work?

Comment: You did say 'Integer division _with decimals_'?

Comment: Seems like since all the answers interpreted your question differently you need to make your question a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For certain limited decimals, you can use Python's float `.as_integer_ratio()` method:

```
>>> 0.5.as_integer_ratio()
(1, 2)
```

For 2/3, which is not exactly representable in decimal, this starts to give less desirable results:

```
>>> (2/3).as_integer_ratio()
(6004799503160661, 9007199254740992)      # approximation of 2/3
```

For arbitrary precision of rational numbers, use [fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) in the Python library:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction('2/3')
Fraction(2, 3)
>>> Frac=fractions.Fraction
>>> Frac('2/3') + Frac('1/3') + Frac('1/10')
Fraction(11, 10)
>>> Frac('2/3') + Frac('1/6') + Frac('1/10')
Fraction(14, 15)
```

Then if you want a more accurate representation of that in decimal, use the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library to convert the integer numerator and denominator to an arbitrary precision decimal:

```
>>> f=Frac('2/3') + Frac('1/6') + Frac('1/10')
>>> f
Fraction(14, 15)
>>> f.numerator
14
>>> f.denominator
15
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(f.numerator) / decimal.Decimal(f.denominator)
Decimal('0.9333333333333333333333333333')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also cast one integer to a float before division.

```
In [1]: float(2)/3
Out[1]: 0.6666666666666666
```

This will prevent integer truncation and give you a result as a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at `decimal.Decimal()`:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> x = decimal.Decimal(2/3)
>>> x
Decimal('0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625')
```

Comment: Doesn't that kinda defeat the use of decimal in the first place?  Maybe better would be `Decimal(2)/Decimal(3)`

Answer (score 0):

`//` is a floor division, it will give you the integer floor of the result. No matter you use `2//3` or `float(2)//3`. You can not keep precision when using `//`.

In my environment (python2.7.6) `2//3` return `0` and `float(2)//3` return `0.0`, neither can keep the precision.

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a direct answer to your question but it will help you to udnerstand.**

**I am posting two link which explains very much details about the implementation:**

- From [python-history-blog](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) from Guido :
- From [PEP-0238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Here is something which we need to aware of:

```
>>> 2/3
0
>>> 2/3.0
0.6666666666666666
>>> 2//3
0
>>> -2//3
-1
>>>
```

[from the PEP-0238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

The current division (/) operator has an ambiguous meaning for
    numerical arguments: it returns the floor of the mathematical
    result of division if the arguments are ints or longs, but it
    returns a reasonable approximation of the division result if the
    arguments are floats or complex.  This makes expressions expecting
    float or complex results error-prone when integers are not
    expected but possible as inputs.

We propose to fix this by introducing different operators for
    different operations: x/y to return a reasonable approximation of
    the mathematical result of the division ("true division"), x//y to
    return the floor ("floor division").  We call the current, mixed
    meaning of x/y "classic division".
- Classic division will remain the default in the Python 2.x
      series; true division will be standard in Python 3.0.

```
- The // operator will be available to request floor division
  unambiguously.

- The future division statement, spelled "from __future__ import
  division", will change the / operator to mean true division
  throughout the module.

- A command line option will enable run-time warnings for classic
  division applied to int or long arguments; another command line
  option will make true division the default.

- The standard library will use the future division statement and
  the // operator when appropriate, so as to completely avoid
  classic division.
```