# Different recursion result from python 2.7.6 and 3.3.3

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am writing a simple sorting code by recursion, and I test it in `Python 2.7.6` and `Python 3.3.3`. But I obtained two different results. The code is following.

```
import math, copy, random, sys
call_count = 0;    # Keep track of number of times of stooge_sort() get called
swap_count = 0;    # Keep track of number of times swapping.
def stooge_sort(a, origin):
    global call_count, swap_count;
    call_count += 1;
    n = len(a);
    m = int(math.ceil(n*2/3));
    if(n == 2 and a[0] > a[1]):
        a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0];
        swap_count += 1;
    elif (n > 2):
        first = copy.deepcopy(a[0:m]);
        a[0:m] = stooge_sort(first, origin);
        second = copy.deepcopy(a[n-m:]);
        a[n-m:] = stooge_sort(second, origin);
        first = copy.deepcopy(a[0:m]);
        a[0:m] = stooge_sort(first, origin);
    return a;

a = [int(random.random() * 100) for i in range(10)];
stooge_sort(a, a);
print("sort function call count = " + str(call_count))
print("swap count = " + str(swap_count));
```

1) if I run in `Python 2.7.6`, I would get incorrect sorting and

```
sort function call count = 40
swap count = 2
```

2) if I run in `Python 3.3.3`, I get correct sorting and

```
sort function call count = 364
swap count = 18
```

So I wonder which part went wrong in `Python 2.7.6`?

Comment: Just a hunch: [Division in Python 2 vs Python 3](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its all because of this line

```
m = int(math.ceil(n*2/3));
```

In Python 2, `n*2/3` gives you a value which is 1 lesser than the actual value since the floating point value is truncated ([since `/` does floor division in Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/1903116)), but in Python 3, it will do the proper floating point division.

To make the program behave consistently, just make sure that you are using floating point numbers

```
m = int(math.ceil(n*2.0/3.0))
```

Comment: `n*2/3` is not the same as `n*(2/3)`. The latter is always 0 as you say, but the former (OP's version) is "only" off by one for many values of n.

Comment: @delnan Oh yeah... Thanks for spotting that :) I fixed the xplanation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your expression `int(math.ceil(n*2/3))` depends on how the `/` operator is defined, and that changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

In Python 2.2 and later, you can also add this to the beginning of your program:

```
from __future__ import division
```

which will cause `/` to always perform floating point division, regardless of its operands. The `//` operator will always perform integer division, whether or not you use the above `__future__` import (although it is only *necessary* when using it).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, to keep you code unambiguous between versions, use `//` for floor division, and ensure you have a float for classic division:

Floor division (from Python 3.3 interpreter):

```
>>> 1//2
0
>>> 2//2
1
```

True division (from Python 2.7 interpreter):

```
>>> float(1)/2
0.5
```

For 2.7, you can also do:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/2
0.5
```