# How can I subset a data frame based on dates, when my dates column is not the index in Python?

Tags: python, date, subset

I have a large dataset with a date column (which is not the index) with the following format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

I would like to create quarterly subsets of this data frame i.e. the data frame `dfQ1` would contain all rows where the date was between month [1 and 4], `dfQ2` would contain all rows where the date was between month [5 and 8], etc... The header of the subsets is the same as that of the main data frame.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas, you can first create a datetime column and then create a quarter column using the [date/time quarter attribute](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-date-components):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
df['datetime'] = [datetime.strptime(dt, date_format) for dt in df['date']]
df['quarter'] = [dt.quarter for dt in df['datetime']]
```

From there you can subset the dataframe with groupby (`df.groupby('quarter')`) or by indexing:

```
dfQ1 = df[df.quarter == 1]
dfQ2 = df[df.quarter == 2]
dfQ3 = df[df.quarter == 3]
dfQ4 = df[df.quarter == 4]
```

Comment: This is more straight forward than the answer given by @metaperture. Thanks a lot, i was able to easily do this for months and weeks as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add a new column containing quarterly information, ie:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
date_to_qtr = lambda dt: 1 + (datetime.strptime(dt, date_format).month-1) // 3
df['qtr'] = df['date'].apply(date_to_qtr)
```

(using the [floordiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) function). Then index on the new column:

```
dfQ1 = df[df.qtr == 1]
dfQ2 = df[df.qtr == 2]
dfQ3 = df[df.qtr == 3]
dfQ4 = df[df.qtr == 4]
```

Or, by then you can just use groupby, `df.groupby("qtr")` (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)).

Comment: This method worked, but I think the quarters are a bit off. For example, dfQ2 contains month 3, where it should only contain months 4,5,6. Same thing for other quarters. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, had an off by one (floordiv likes 0-indexed, months and quarters are 1-index). Should be fixed above.

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly :). Can you explain though what the `//3` is? If i also wanted to include a "month" column and a "week" column similar to "qtr" how can I adjust the `date_to_qtr` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Pandas.

dfQ1 = df[(df.date > Qstartdate) & (df.date < Qenddate)]

Comment: I tried putting `2013-01-01` as my Qstartdate and `2013-04-01` as my Qenddate, but i got the following error `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int`. How should i write these parameters? Sorry I am new to Python and Pandas, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: hmmm, whats the data type of your date in your df?  You can do df.dtypes to find that out.

Comment: it says type `object`.I guess its a string. I tried changing it to a date using strptime but I still had a problem. I guess i'm doing something wrong. @metaperture's method worked well though.

Comment: Ok, glad you're up and running