# A function that would give the middle letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f(x):
```

I'm trying to make a function, f(x), that would return the middle letters eg.

```
f(["a", "b", "c", "d" "e"])
```

outputs:

```
["c"]
```

and

```
f(["a", "b", "c", "d" "e", "f"])
```

because there is an even number of letters, outputs:

```
["c", "d"]
```

Comment: Can you share your approach ?

Comment: This sounds like homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force way

```
def f(x):
    l = len(x)
    if l%2 == 0:
        return x[l//2-1:l//2+1]
    return [x[l//2]]
```

Demo

```
>>> f(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
['c']
>>> f(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
['d', 'e']
>>> f(["an", "pat", "but", "bet", "ten", "king"])
['but', 'bet']
```

Small-Note: Refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) to understand the difference between `/`and `//` operators in python

Comment: Well `//` will work the same for 2.x and 3.x... using `/` will break in 3.x

Comment: would this also work for f(["an", "pat", "but", "bet", "ten", "king"]), outputting ["but", "bet"]?

Comment: it says "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given"

Comment: Aha! You missed the square brackets `[...]` inside the parenthesis `(...)`. Try passing it inside square brackets as you have shown

Comment: Oh woops. Okay I tried again. Says: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "program.py", line 4, in f
    return x[l/2-1:l/2+1]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method"

Comment: It works fine for an odd number of words/letters but same error for an even number of words

Answer (score 1):

```
 def f(x):
        l = len(x)
        if l % 2 == 0:
            return [x[l/2 - 1], x[l/2]]
        else:
            return [x[l/2]]





 print f(["a", "b", "c", "d" "e"])
 print f(["a", "b", "c", "d" "e", "f"])
```

Comment: the else is not needed, you cannot return twice

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ur right but I like putting in clear logic

Answer (score 1):

So you should have something like :

```
def f(x):
  if len(x) % 2 == 0:
    return [x[len(x)/2], x[len(x)/2+1]]
  else:
    return x[ceil(len(x)/2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x[round(len(l)/2-0.5):round(len(l)/2+0.5)]
... 
>>> f(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
['c', 'd']
>>> f(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
['c']
```