# Python function not returning type as expected

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

While running a unit test to confirm the output type, I am getting an AssertionError: != type 'int' on this function and cannot figure out why.

```
    def averagePix(image):
        totalNumber = image.size
        counter = 0

        it = np.nditer(image)
        for (m) in it:
            counter = counter + m

        average = counter / totalNumber
        return average
```

I need to return a type int. If I comment out the np.nditer block, it passes the test with type int. Can someone please help me figure out how this block is screwing things up?

```
        it = np.nditer(image)
        for (m) in it:
            counter = counter + m
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the dtype of `counter` after iteration?

Comment: This is Python 2, I will check the dtype (as well as the other suggestions here) when I have access to my personal computer later in the day. Thanks everyone. I think the error said something along the lines of "ndtype 32", if I remember right?

Comment: Did the assertion complain that the type is `numpy.int32`?  That's just a Python `int` with a `numpy` wrapper.  That's different from complaining that it is a `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the neatest solution, but you can also convert it to `int`.

Eg

```
average = counter / totalNumber

return int(average)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want `average` to be an integer you should use integer division `//`.

Eg:

```
average = counter // totalNumber
```

In Python 2, `a / b` will give an integer result if both `a` and `b` are integers. But in Python 3 `a / b` will always result in a float.

FWIW, in Python 2 you can get `/` to behave the Python 3 way by putting

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the start of your script.

See [In Python, what is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/4014959)

Answer (score 2):

See if you're importing division from `__future__` at some point.

Also, see if image.size is not float maybe.

Also, use numpy directly for averaging. :P

Answer (score 1):

In an IPython3 session, I reproduce your code with:

```
In [228]: image=np.ones((4,4),dtype=int)
In [230]: counter=0
In [231]: it=np.nditer(image)
In [232]: for (m) in it:
   .....:     counter = counter + m

In [233]: counter
Out[233]: 16

In [234]: type(counter)
Out[234]: numpy.int32

In [235]: average = counter/image.size
In [236]: type(average)
Out[236]: numpy.float64

In [237]: average = counter//image.size # force integer division
In [238]: type(average)
Out[238]: numpy.int32
```

Both of those `average` values will fail a `type()==int` test.  The `numpy.int32` number has a `numpy` wrapper around an `int`.  Usually that's not a problem, but to satisfy the test you'd have test `average.item()` - take it out of the wrapper.

`nditer` is actually feeding your `counter` addition an array

```
In [240]: type(m)
Out[240]: numpy.ndarray
In [241]: m
Out[241]: array(1)
```

You could get around that by applying `item` to `m`:

```
for (m) in it:
    counter = counter + m.item()
```

Why are you using `nditer`?  To learn how to use it?  This isn't the best application for it.  Alternatives include

```
counter = np.sum(image)
counter = np.sum.flat(image)
average = np.average(image)
```

These results will still be `int32` or `float64`.  So you still have to  deal with assertion test.  Does it really have to be `int`?

Comment: thank you very much for this. I think you've identified the issue exactly. Yes, I do need to return an int; there is no getting around that. I'm using nditer due to my lack of Python knowledge, but if the other options will still not return an int, you are right; that won't help me much. I simply need to iterate over each pixel in an ndarray, sum all their values, and divide by the total number of pixels (image.size). Perhaps i'm not using the best approach to do this?

Comment: counter = counter + m.item() worked, thank you hpaulj!