# scipy.signal.filtfilt returning nan values

Tags: python, filter, wav, nan

I'm trying to design a bandstop filter and it's failing to give me a valid (wav file) output due to nan values in the filter output.

The input is a simple speech clip a few seconds long.

```
def bandstop(x, f1, f2):
    fs, samples = wavfile.read(x)
    N = 6  # filter order
    rs = 60  # stop band minimum attenuation
    b, a = signal.cheby2(N, rs, [2 * f1 / fs, 2 * f2 / fs], btype='bandstop')  
    xfiltered = signal.filtfilt(b, a, samples)  # applying filter
    wavfile.write("xfiltered.wav", fs, xfiltered)  # returns unreadable file?
```

I'm testing this with a simple

```
print xfiltered
```

to find nan values. Any solutions?

Comment: what *is* it returning?

Comment: A .wav file which refuses to open / contains 0 values when forced, and when "xfiltered" is printed pre wav conversion I just have "[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]"

Comment: What is the value of `f1`, `f2`, `fs`?

Comment: f1 = 500 f2 = 5000 though I plan to play with those once this is working. fs is 48000

Comment: If you are using Python2, [`/` performs integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/190597) on ints. So if `f1, f2, fs = 500, 5000, 48000` then `[2 * f1 / fs, 2 * f2 / fs]` would equal `[0, 0]`. Make sure to convert the inputs to floats (e.g. `fs = 48000.0` suffices) before performing the division.

Comment: Thankyou! Ridiculous I hadn't noticed that one, simple