# Dividing every value in one list by every value in another list

Tags: python, math

I am writing a function to find all the rational zeros of a polynomial and in need to divide each number in a list by each number in a list
Ex.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60]
list2 = [1,2,3,6]

zeros = [1/1,2/1,3/1,4/1,...,1/2,2/2,3/2,4/2,...1/3,2/3,3/3,4/3,etc...]
```

How would I accomplish this?
Edit:
Here is my code:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def factor(x):
    x = abs(x)
    factors = []
    new_factors = []
    for n in range(1,x):
        if x % n == 0:
            factors.append(n)
            new_factors.append(n)
    for y in factors:
        new_factors.append(y * -1)
    new_factors = sorted(new_factors)
    return new_factors
print(factor(8))


def find_zeros(fnctn,pwr):
    last = fnctn[len(fnctn)]
    first = fnctn[0]
    P_s = factor(last)
    Q_s = factor(first)
    p_zeros = []
```

Would I do something like this:

```
for x in P_s:
for y in Q_s:
    p_zeros.append(x/y)
```

Comment: Show us the code !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
zeros = []
for i in list1:
    zeros.extend([i/j for j in list2])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed were nested for loops

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60] 
list2 = [1,2,3,6]
zeros = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        zeros.append(x/y)
print(zeros)
```

output:
`[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 2.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 4.0, 2.0, 1.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 5.0, 2.5, 1.6666666666666667, 0.8333333333333334, 6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 10.0, 5.0, 3.3333333333333335, 1.6666666666666667, 12.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 15.0, 7.5, 5.0, 2.5, 20.0, 10.0, 6.666666666666667, 3.3333333333333335, 30.0, 15.0, 10.0, 5.0, 60.0, 30.0, 20.0, 10.0]`
I appreciate your help everyone!

Comment: In your question, you ask for `y/x`, here you put `x/y`. Also your `floats` are imprecise of course and this is less elegant than the `itertools.product` solution, although I appreciate it may be easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution without itertools, for whomever may want it:

To get this result:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60]
list2 = [1,2,3,6]

zeros = [1/1,2/1,3/1,4/1,...,1/2,2/2,3/2,4/2,...1/3,2/3,3/3,4/3,etc...]
```

**English Explanation**

You can iterate a variable, say `i`, through `range(len(list1))` to get the index of each element in `list1` in order.

To get the corresponding index in `list2` just floor divide `i` by `len(list1)/float(len(list2))`.

Then we'll take the element from `list1` and divide by the element in `list2` and add that to some initially empty list (you named this zeros).

**Python Code** (correct me if I'm wrong it's untested an hastily written)

```
zeros = []
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60]
list2 = [1,2,3,6]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    zeros.append(list1[i] / float(list2[i//(len(list1)/float(len(list2))))])
print(zeros)
```

**Postword**

You didn't mention what version of python you're using. This will influence the default behavior when dividing integers. See [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) for an explanation of division for the major versions of python. I expect you want float division because 1/4 with evaluate to zero with floor division. The code I wrote should work for either version of python, as 1//2 is explicit floor division and 1/float(2) is explicit float division.