# What is the meaning of "//" in fully_connected_feed.py

Tags: tensorflow

I am studying TensorFlow with Python 2.7.6.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#tensorflow-mechanics-101

From above page, I can obtain fully_connected_feed.py.

In the file, I see

```
# And run one epoch of eval.
true_count = 0  # Counts the number of correct predictions.
steps_per_epoch = data_set.num_examples // FLAGS.batch_size
```

What is the meaning of the "//" operator?

I am trying to find the meaning in API doc, without success.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/index.html

Comment: Without really knowing any python at all, is it integer division?

Comment: I added python 2.7.6.

Comment: With your comment "integer division",  I could find the information. Thank you very much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compatibility with Python 2 and Python 3, TensorFlow consistently uses Python 3 division operators, using a [`from __future__ import division`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8915f0f8072c406ae3fe0dff888f51b4cad02d7d/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py#L19) statement at the top of every file.

As Trejkaz [points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968211/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-fully-connected-feed-py#comment67216124_39968211), in Python 3, the `//` operator means [floor division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/183870/3574081) (or integer division): i.e. the result is equivalent to `floor(data_set.num_examples / FLAGS.batch_size)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the keyword "floor division", which says what kind of interger division is used. This will help me to understand more.