# Calculating sum of digits using recursive function. Can someone explain?

Tags: python, string, function, recursion

I have a code that works however I do not fully understand how this line works:

```
return (myFunc%10) + numbersum(myFunc//10)
```

Why does this line calculate the sum of the digits?

Here is the full code

```
def numbersum(myFunc):
    if myFunc == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (myFunc%10) + numbersum(myFunc//10)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad. What don't you understand? Recursion? Mod? Division? Addition? Checking for equality?

Comment: "Why does this line calculate the sum of the digits?" That's the purpose of the function, so sum the digits of a number.

Comment: Changing `myFunc` to `number` is a step in the right direction

Comment: Usign a variable name of `myFunc` for something that is a number does not helping understanding but add `print(myFunc%10, myFunc//10)` before the return line and you should start getting an idea of how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of the line you don't understand since you didn't specify, but I'm going to assume it's one of:

1. modulo operator (%);
2. integer division operator (//); or
3. recursion

(1) is easily googled, and there are plenty of good explanations (for example, the first line in [Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)): "In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus)."

(2) See [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) for an explanation of the // operator.

(3) A function calling itself, as this one does, is an example of recursion, and the function is said to be a "recursive function." A key component of a recursive function is the "base case," a case where the function does *not* call itself. Without a base case calling the function once would enter into an infinite loop where the function calls itself forever. The if-statement in this code defines a base case.

A common pattern in recursion is, on the recursive call, to pass to the function an argument that is "simpler" than the argument it received (in that it is "closer" to the base case).

Let's run through a quick example. If I call `numbersum(123)`:

1. Is `123 == 0`? **No**. So, `numbersum(123)` equals `123%10`, which is 3, plus `numbersum(123//10)`, which is `numbersum(12)`.
2. Now we have to figure out `numbersum(12)`. Same steps. Is `12==0`? **No**. So, `numbersum(12)` equals `12%10`, which is 2, plus `numbersum(12//10)`, which is `numbersum(1)`.
3. So what is `numbersum(1)`? Same steps. Is `1==0`? **No**. So, `numbersum(1)` equals `1%%10`, which is 0, plus `numbersum(1//10)`, which is `numbersum(0)`.
4. Lastly, what is `numbersum(0)`? Is `0==0`? **Yes**! The base case is hit here. So `numbersum(0)` equals 0.

If you look back through these steps, you will see that

`numbersum(123) = 3 + numbersum(12)
numbersum(12) = 2 + numbersum(1)
numbersum(1) = 1 + numbersum(0)
numbersum(0) = 0`

Working youre way back up the chain using basic algebraic substitution, you get the correct answer: 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the number `123` stored in `myFunc` then `myFunc%10` is going to get you `3` because `123%10 == 3`,  you then do `myFunc//10` which gets you `12`.  you pass this to your function which is where the recursion happens.  So you end up with `3` + The result of your function being called on `12`.  This repeats until you have summed all the digits.

Answer (score 0):

- `(myFunc%10)` [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 10 - Takes the one's digit
- `numbersum(myFunc//10)` recursively calls the function, dividing the number by 10, therefore "chopping off" the ones digit.
- Until... `myFunc == 0` (which really should be `<=`), in which case `0` is returned, added to the previous ones digit from the call "up the stack"
- All numbers summed back up the call stack until you have added all the numbers