# Plotting in pandas: no property kind when using subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm an absolute pandas/matplotlib beginner and I can't figure out this issue after quite a few searches.

Just learned that in order to format dates (basically space them out), I need to work an additional thing called `fig` (for figure):

```
fig, tg = plt.subplots(1)
tg.plot(pandoc['date_time'], pandoc['total_goals'], kind="bar")
tg.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

However, when I try to change my data `kind` to `bar, I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: Unknown property kind

It worked perfectly when I simply did

```
pandoc['total_goals'].plot(kind='bar')
```

But then `mdates.DateFormatter` wouldn't work.

I'm missing something. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas DataFrames, such as `pandoc`, have a `plot` method with [a `kind` parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).
So it is possible to make a plot using

```
pandoc.plot(x='date_time', y='total_goals', kind="bar", ax=tg)
```

Notice that `ax=tg` is used to tell `pandoc` to draw on the matplotlib Axes, `tg`.

---

In contrast, matplotlib Axes, such as `tg`, have a `plot` method, but `tg.plot` [does not have a `kind` parameter](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot). Instead, to make a bar plot with an Axes object, call its [`tg.bar` method](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar).

---

Using the `pandoc.plot` method, you could make a bar plot using something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 150
pandoc = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='M'),
                   'total_goals':np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
fig, tg = plt.subplots(1)
pandoc.plot(x='date_time', y='total_goals', kind="bar", ax=tg)

labels, skip = ['']*N, 10
labels[skip//2::skip] = pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[skip//2::skip]
tg.set_xticklabels(labels)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

### [image]

Note that `tg.set_xticklabels` is used to set the xticklabels instead of `mdates.DateFormatter`. When making a bar plot the underlying bar plot `xtick` values are integers:

```
In [21]: tg.get_xticks()
Out[26]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

You can only use `mdates.DateFormatter` when the `xtick` values are dates.
Since a bar plot has a fixed number of bars, there is no advantage to using a dynamic formatter like [`mticker.FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter); you are best off simply setting the `xticklabels` using the `Axes.set_xticklabels` method.

---

```
labels = ['']*N
```

creates a list of `N` empty strings. For example, `['']*2` evaluates to `['', '']`.

```
x, y = a, b
```

is [equivalent to](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

```
x = a
y = b
```

So `labels, skip = ['']*N, 10` is equivalent to

```
labels = ['']*N
skip = 10
```

---

Python slice notation, e.g. `x[start:end:step]` is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/190597). For example,

```
In [227]: x = list('ABCDEFGHIJK'); x
Out[227]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']

In [228]: x[1::3]
Out[228]: ['B', 'E', 'H', 'K']    <-- the first item is x[1], and then we pick up every 3rd item
```

So in the code above, `pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` is a sequence of strings and if we call it `x`, then `x[skip//2::skip]` is a new sequence which starts with `x[skip//2]` and then steps by `skip` amount.

---

`skip//2` divides `skip` by 2 using [integer-division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/190597).

---

`labels` begins as a list of `N` empty strings. With `skip=10`, the assignment

```
labels[skip//2::skip] = pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[skip//2::skip]
```

replaces every 10th element (starting at `skip//2`) with a date string from `pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`.

---

`pandoc['date_time']` is a time series. 
`pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` uses the [`Series.dt.strftime` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format the dates into date-strings in `%Y-%m-%d` format.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. However, I'm getting the dates squished again. (Not spaced - I have over 150 bars)

Comment: I'm assuming it's because I'm not setting the periods the way I'm reading to the DataFrame (I'm reading from an SQL query)

Comment: Do you want to group some of the dates together (i.e. make a histogram) or do you want 150 bars? If you want 150 bars, you do want an xticklabel for each bar, or can we label, say, every 10th bar?

Comment: I want 150 bars, not all of them need to be labeled though (not even sure I'm using the right terminology)

Comment: I've modified the example to show how you could label every Nth bar.

Comment: Thanks again. While I don't really understand what the lines `labels, skip = ['']*N, 10` and 
`labels[skip//2::skip] = pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[skip//2::skip]` are doing yet, this is one of the more elaborate and concise answers I've had here. Cheers!

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation for those two lines.

Comment: Wonderful. Why are we doing `skip//2` and not just `skip`?

Comment: It's easiest to see with an example. Try changing the code above to `labels[::skip] = pandoc['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[::skip]`. You'll see the labels begin at the left edge, and there is space on the right with no label. I tried to "fix" that by shifting the labels by half the skip amount so that the labels are more centered relative to the edges of the plot.