# Function for converting ratios (Python [2.7])

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a function that goes like this:

```
def ratio_transform(n, h, nh):
     ...
```

In other words, your fraction is n / h and the returned value is x / nh

For example, I want to convert 5 / 100 to x / 1000 (n is 5, h is 100 and nh is 1000)

My code goes:

```
def ratio_transform(n, h, nh):
    return (n / h) * nh
```

But ratio_transform(5, 100, 1000) always returns 0.0, when it should return 0.5

Is it a logic error, or a data type error?

Comment: 5/100 in Python 2 is 0.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/5647260

Answer (score 1):

```
def ratio_transform(n, h, nh):
    return (n / float(h)) * nh
```

Comment: When I call ratio_transform(5, 100, 1000), it returns 50.0