# Python Finding the median function error

Tags: python, function, median

Could anyone please explain to me why this is not working? The error message I'm getting is: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float.

```
def median(lst):
    s = sorted(lst)
    l = len(lst)/2
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        print((s[l] + s[l-1])/2.0)
    else:
        print(s[l])
median([3,3,5,6,7,8,1])
```

Comment: well... list indices must be integers or slices, not float. So force l to be an integer

Comment: You are dividing `len(lst)` by two, which yields a float. You can use integer division instead (`//`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error you made is in calculating `l`

dividing using operator `/` returns actual division i.e. a floating point value while `//` returns only quotient i.e. an integer

hence

you should calculate `l` as follows

```
l = len(lst) // 2
```

or convert `l` to `int` using

```
l  = int(l)
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

If `len(lst)` is odd then `l` becomes a float.

Interestingly the code you've written is probably valid in Python 2 as it uses integer division if both the numerator and denominator are integers.

However in Python 3 true division is used by default.

For more information see: [In Python 2, what is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-2-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) and https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator