# Get a decimal point result upto n number of precision in python

Tags: python, math, floating-point, decimal

I have an app that has some complex mathematical operations leading to very small amount in results like 0.000028 etc. Now If I perform some calculation in javascript like (29631/1073741824) it gives me result as 0.000027596019208431244 whereas the same calculation in python with data type float gives me 0.0. How can I increase the number of decimal points in results in python

Comment: Use `decimal`: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html, where arbitrary precision can be set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in a lack of decimal points, it's that in Python 2 integer division produces an integer result. This means that 29631/1073741824 yields 0 rather than the float you are expecting. To work around this, you can use a float for either operand:

```
>>> 29631.0/1073741824
2.7596019208431244e-05
```

This [changed in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), where the division operator does the expected thing. You can use a `from __future__` import to [turn on the new behavior in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/1600898):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 29631/1073741824
2.7596019208431244e-05
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Python 3.x, you should try this :

```
print(str(float(29631)/1073741824))
```

Comment: In Python 3 that should not be necessary, as `29631/1073741824` will calculate the expected (float) result.