# Arrange a Text file using python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, file

Hey I want to arrange a text file using python. My python code is working perfectly but it's not give me expected answer. Let me explain
I have a text file same like this:-

```
serial
name
phone 
gmail
1
blah blah
55555
blah@blah.com
```

I wrote my script like this :-

```
out=open('out.txt','w')  
with open('blah.txt') as b:
    i=1
    for line in b:
        if i==1:
            out.write(line)
            i=i+1
        elif type(line)==int:
            out.write('\n'+line)
        elif type(line)==str:
            out.write('\b\t'+line)
        else:
            pass
out.close()
```

I didn't wrote entire program but it's like this. But it's give me my output same as my input. Am I missing something?

My expected Ans is:-

```
serial    name      phone   gmail
1        blah blah   55555   blah@blah.com
```

Comment: How do you want to arrange the text file? What is your expected output? Can you edit your question and add this to it?

Comment: I did it Please Check.

Comment: _"My python code is working perfectly but it's not give me expected answer."_ - that is a good one.

Comment: :) I mean without any error :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to transform lines of text to columns. This code is supposing that in your file `blah.txt` you are having same amount of headers and values:

```
with open('blah.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('out.txt','w',newline='') as f_out:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f_in.readlines()]
    headers, values = lines[:len(lines)//2], lines[len(lines)//2:]
    for h in headers:
        f_out.write(h + '\t\t')
    f_out.write('\n')
    for v in values:
        f_out.write(v + '\t\t')
    f_out.write('\n')
```

With this the out.txt will be:

```
serial      name        phone       gmail       
1       blah blah       55555       blah@blah.com
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what \\2 does?

Comment: @AnirbanSingha It's called integer division - here in this question it's properly explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-2-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.center()` for alignment, and need to add a \n after half the lines are written:

Create test file for [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
text ="""serial
name
phone 
gmail
1
blah blah
55555
blah@blah.com"""

fn = "t.txt"

with open(fn,"w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Process file:

```
fn = "t.txt"

lines = []
with open(fn,"r") as f:
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

# what is the longest data  items? space others accordingly:
longest = max(len(x) for x in lines)

with open("t2.txt","w") as f: 
    # write first half of rows
    for header in lines[:(len(lines)//2)]:
        f.write( str.center( header, longest+2))
    f.write("\n")
    # write second half of rows
    for data in lines[len(lines)//2:]:
        f.write( str.center( data, longest+2))
    f.write("\n")
```

Read back in and output for verification:

```
print("\n")
with open("t2.txt","r") as r:
    print(r.read())
```

Output:

```
   serial          name          phone          gmail     
     1          blah blah        55555      blah@blah.com
```

Answer (score -2):

You aren't closing the output file:

Try adding `out.close()` at the end.

Comment: If I'm not wrong opening file with "with" automatically close file. when loop finished. link:- http://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/

Comment: @AnirbanSingha That is correct, but you only use `with` on the input file. The output file is not affected by this particular usage.

Comment: oops! I did add on my code but forgot to mention let me edit again :) . Please Check my question again and try to give me a proper ans. As I give expected answer.

Comment: @AnirbanSingha Better yet, use `with` for both files.

Comment: Can you please give me your full ans. @zvone

Comment: @AnirbanSingha `with open('out.txt','w') as out, open('blah.txt') as b:`