# The math calculations behind using (%, //) in python by applying (Decimal(), signed numbers )?

Tags: python, decimal, division, reminders

I was trying to understand the math behind calculations using / and // and % operators by doing some trials and found the results are similar to calculator only when using Decimal() but without it the results kinda confusing, i tried to add comments `#No Idea`to my code to mark the points i don't understand,for example:

1. in this trial for % operator by applying signed and unsigned number the results and with and without Decimal() the results are :

   ```
   >>> 9%5    #This result will be the reminder
   4         
   >>> (-9)%5    #No Idea
   1
   >>> Decimal(9)% Decimal(5)    #This result will be the reminder
   Decimal('4')  
   >>> Decimal(-9)% Decimal(5)    #The result will be the signed reminder
   Decimal('-4')
   ```
2. in this trial for // operator and using signed and unsigned number with and without Decimal() the results are :

   ```
   >>> 9//5    #int result
   1
   >>> -9//5    #No Idea
   -2
   >>> Decimal(9)/Decimal(5)    #Same result as using calculator
   Decimal('1.8')
   >>> Decimal(-9)//Decimal(5)    #No Idea
   Decimal('-1')
   ```

Please consider that this question is not a duplicate and i have done some research to get an answer but i found some answered questions that explain only about // operator using only positive signed numbers and doesn't include information about negative signed numbers or using the Decimal() and doesn't have answer about % operator.

so,It will be helpful if someone knows why the results are different and how they are calculated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python 2, what is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-2-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)

Comment: See the beginning of the [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) section of the documentation, especially the part about the sign of result that the `%` (modulo) operator yields. When you're doing  research, the documentation is often a good place to look—at least with Python.

Comment: I don't think thi duplication is correct, as this question handles the difference between the built-in integer and the `Decimal` class primarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, the OP is asking about the different behavior between Python integers and `Decimal`s. I don't think there is any good reason for it. Both choices are possible, but it is a bit confusing for the user that they differ.

Let's call the numerator `n`, the denominator `d` and split the result in the interger result `i` and the remainder `r`. This means that

```
n // d = i
n % d = r
```

For the operations to make sense, we need

```
i * d + r == n
```

For `n = -9` and `d = 5` we see that this is uphold for both `i = -1, r = -4` and for `i = -2, r = 1` as can be seen by

```
(i = -1, r = -4) => -1 * 5 + -4 == -9
(i = -2, r = 1) => -2 * 5 + 1 == -9
```

Now, in Python integer division is defined as always truncate towards minus infinity (down) and the `Decimal` implementation has chosen to round towards zero. That means that positive values are truncated/rounded down, whereas negative values are rounded up.

Rounding towards zero is the choice made also made in the C language. However, my personal opinion is that the Python choice is much more sane, specifically coming from a hardware background. And given that this is the choice made in Python, I think it is strange (and bad) that `Decimal` has chosen to do as in the C language.

Comment: "I don't think there is any good reason for it." Not sure about "good", but there's definitely a reason. The `decimal` module follows a [standard](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/). That standard specifies a [remainder](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refremain) operation where the sign of the result matches that of the dividend (unlike the behaviour of % with integers, where the sign of the result matches that of the divisor). So it's somewhat natural to have `%` for the `Decimal` type correspond to that remainder operation.

Comment: The standard also specifies [divide-integer](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refdivint), with semantics matching those of `//` for `Decimal` objects.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, it follows _a_ standard. But it is strange choise of standard when you get different results for the standard arithmetic operations.

Comment: Shrug. It's not as though there was a huge variety of standards to choose from back in 2003 when the `decimal` module was planned, and it's definitely better to follow a standard than to just make up all the corner cases. So maybe it wasn't the perfect standard; it was just better than the few other options. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Well, there was also the option to follow the behavior of Python integers, which would lead to fewer surprises. That I personally happen to prefer the way it is in Python, would just be a bonus. :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation for the  behaviour of integers

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> Division of integers yields a float, while floor division of integers
>   results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical division
>   with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

Therefore, an integer division (`//`) of negative negative and positive number works as follows:

```
-9 // 5 == floor(-9 / 5) == floor(-1.8) == -2
```

The modulo operator is the remainder of the integer division, i.e. `x % y = x - x // y * y`. In your example:

```
-9 % 5 == -9 - (-9 // 5 * 5) == (-9) - (-2 * 5) == (-9) - (-10) == 1
```

The documentation also says:

> The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its
>   second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly
>   smaller than the absolute value of the second operand.

But that comes naturally from the formula above, e.g.:

```
9 % -5 == 9 - (9 // (-5) * (-5)) == 9 - (-2 * (-5)) == 9 - 10 == -1
```

---

### `decimal.Decimal` is different

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) explains the difference well:

> There are some small differences between arithmetic on Decimal objects
>   and arithmetic on integers and floats. When the remainder operator `%`
>   is applied to Decimal objects, the sign of the result is the sign of
>   the dividend rather than the sign of the divisor:
>
> ```
> >>> (-7) % 4
> 1
> >>> Decimal(-7) % Decimal(4)
> Decimal('-3')
> ```
>
> The integer division operator `//` behaves analogously, returning the
>   integer part of the true quotient (truncating towards zero) rather
>   than its floor, so as to preserve the usual identity `x == (x // y) * y
>   + x % y`:
>
> ```
> >>> -7 // 4
> -2
> >>> Decimal(-7) // Decimal(4)
> Decimal('-1')
> ```