# What is the inverse of this for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, shearsort

I have a code that shears an image in python, and I do that using forward mapping. However, my assignment also requires me to do backward mapping, i.e. finding the input from the output. My code looks as follows, and my question is: What does the inverse of this for loop look like in code form?

```
for y in range(height):
   for x in range(50, 450):
        img[int(x * By + y), int(x + y * Bx)] = img[y, x]
```

height is the height of the image, img is said image. Bx and By are just factors, numbers I choose myself.
For clarification, the formula of shearing looks like this in maths:

x' = x + y · Bx

y' = x · By + y

My guess is this, but I get an index out of bounds error:

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(50, 450):
        img[int(x * 1/By - y), int(x - y * 1/Bx)] = img[y, x]
```

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me

Comment: You should catch the error and print the values that generates an index out of bounds. This should help you understanding the problem in your calculus.

Comment: Seconding @MaximeChéramy. Here's an idea as to what might be happening though: your error implies that `[int(x * 1/By - y), int(x - y * 1/Bx)]` isn't in `img`. You might have to reconsider the ranges you're choosing when doing the inverse shear. Perhaps the image you are unshearing doesn't have the same dimensions as the image you sheared.

Comment: You might be a victim of [integer division rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division). Maybe try `1.0 / By` and `1.0 / Bx`.

Answer (score 1):

Your output has different dimensions than the input. You can't use the original ranges for output indexes. I think the easiest option would be to just invert the assignment statement:

```
for y in range(height):
   for x in range(50, 450):
        img_1[y, x] = img_2[int(x * By + y), int(x + y * Bx)]
```