# My percentage here apparently doesn't display correctly the result and I am unsure why,

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, percentage

This is what I have - it displays but the percentage isn't correct - ps. it's a csv file on information of people who were on board titanic - I am trying to find the percentage of women of the total who were on board - thank you for any help!

```
    import csv


       f = open('titanic.csv', 'r');
       lecteur = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
       count=0
       total = 0
       for ligne in lecteur:
            total=total+1
       if ligne[3]=="female":
           count=count+1

        perc=(count/(total-1)) *100


        print("Total:", total-1)
        print("Pourcentage des femmes:", perc )
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3, as [division works differently between versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/183870/1270789). Please edit the tags to indicate which. Furthermore, please describe how the percentage is not correct - what value do you see, and what value do you expect?

Comment: Ah, apologies its my first time using this - I'm using python 3. And so the total displays, as 1309, and the percentage of women displays as 35.861 - honestly I am not sure of the value I expect but I know it is wrong, as we must submit the answer for an assignment and you have to keep going until you get the correct answer - so I am unsure what the correct answer is, I just know it's not the value they are looking for! Thank you

Comment: How many women are in the file?

Comment: In Python 3 you will have the correct behaviour for division, so that's not a problem.

Comment: 466 women @barmar

Comment: Print `count` in the script to see if that's correct.

Comment: That is what I just did and it is indeed correct. But it is not the correct answer yet in my assignment so I am very confused,

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement needs to be inside the `for` loop. Also, you can use the `len()` function to get `total`, you don't need to increment the variable yourself.

```
total = len(lecteur) - 1 #subtract the header line
for ligne in lecteur:
    if ligne[3] == "female":
        count += 1

perc = count/total * 100
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, actually I do need to subtract one in as the first entry in the csv is a header, not a value. And I do have the if in my for loop, so still no joy I am afraid

Comment: It's not in the loop in the code you posted. Indentation is critical in Python, make sure the question exactly matches your real script.

Comment: Yes I have realised, it is my first question after all!