# What is a result of Integer division a decimal?

Tags: python, integer-division

I'm not sure how integer division actually works with decimal. Considering these two examples on `Python 3.x`:

```py
4/0.4 = 10.0
4//0.4 = 9.0
```

Regular division gives 10 but the integer division of 4 by 0.4 results in 9.0.

Do you know the behavior of integer division with decimal and why the result is this way?

Comment: `//` is floor division, not "integer division".

Comment: According to [the official Python 3 reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) the `//` operator is *floor division*, not integer division (how would an integer division using non-integer values even work?). As for the result, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Combine with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division for full effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)

Answer (score 1):

The CPython's implementation of floor division of a float number, as either a dividend or a divisor, lies in the [`float_floor_div`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6d43f6f081023b680d9db4542d19b9e382149f0a/Objects/floatobject.c#L665) function, which calls the [`float_divmod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6d43f6f081023b680d9db4542d19b9e382149f0a/Objects/floatobject.c#L618) function (which implements the `divmod` function) for the actual calculation, which, with the following lines of code:

```
mod = fmod(vx, wx);
div = (vx - mod) / wx;
...
floordiv = floor(div);
```

tells you that the way that floor division works for a float number is to first call the `fmod` function to obtain the remainder of the division, subtract the remainder from the dividend `vx`, and then divide it by the divisor `wx`, before applying the `floor` function on the resulting quotient `div`.

And if you try performing the modulo operation of `4 % 0.4`, expecting it to be `0` because 4 / 0.4 should be mathematically 10:

```
>>> 4 % 0.4
0.3999999999999998
```

You'll see the classic [floating error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) inherent from the way decimal numbers are approximated by the binary system. As a result 0.4 is actually stored as something slightly greater than 0.4, which you can verify by instantiating a high-precision `Decimal` object with 0.4:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.4)
Decimal('0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625')
```

which is why 4 % 0.4 has a remainder of 0.3999999999999998 instead of 0, and as a result, with the way `float_divmod` calculated the quotient, by first subtracting the remainder from the dividend, you get:

```
>>> 4 - 4 % 0.4
3.6
```

so naturally,

```
>>> (4 - 4 % 0.4) / 0.4
9.0
```