# Difference between this C++ function and Python function

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I have function in C++ that returns positive number `a` magnified `b` times. In C++ this function runs with no errors but I want to use this function in Python. Could anyone tell why this function returns result in `C++` but does not return it in Python or where I made a mistake in Python code?

I know that I can write this function in many other ways and that this function may not be the best solution but what is wrong with THIS particular example? What I have to do to run this in Python without writing new, better function obviously. Why I can run this code in C++ but not in Python?

**C++ CODE:-**

```
int exp(int a,int b){
    int result=1;
    while(b!=0){
        if(b%2==1){
          result*=a;
        }
        b/=2;
        a*=a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**PYTHON CODE:-**

```
def exp(a,b):
  result=1
  while b!=0:
    if b%2==1:
      result*=a
    b/=2
    a*=a
  return result
```

Is something wrong with while condition in Python???

Comment: `b /= 2` -- not integer divide in Python 3; compare to `b //= 2`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/2864740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using floating point division in the Python code:

```
b/=2
```

You want integer division:

```
b //= 2
```

Comment: Only for python 3.x as previous versions worked well with `/` and treated it's output as integer.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Question tagged with python3.

Comment: I was just trying to inform the readers of this answer, if they are not aware of this fact.

Comment: Yes I am using python-3.x now, anyway thanks all of u guys, it helped. That was really simple.