# wrong output when dividing by 10

Tags: python-3.x

input = 55555555555555555

while dividing by 10 I am getting the output as 5555555555555556.0

```
number = int(input())
n = number
s = 0;
m = number
while(n>=1):
    print(n)
    x=int(n)%10
    print(x)
    n=int(n)/int(10)
    print(n)
    s=s+x
print(s)
```

need help.

Comment: look at [`divmod` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)

Comment: @21guns What is the objective of your code?. Can you write the input and the expected output for your code.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a float result because the operator `/` return a float number.

In Python3, use `//` which ensures a integer return value.

Try `n = n // 10`.