# Don't understand this TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python

Receiving a TypeError when trying to run:

```
File "/home/XX/PycharmProjects/rogue_like/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tcod/libtcodpy.py", line 1236, in console_put_char
    lib.TCOD_console_put_char(_console(con), x, y, _int(c), flag)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

```
Class Object:

    def __init__(self, x, y, char, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.color = color

    def draw(self):
        libtcod.console_set_default_foreground(con, self.color)
        libtcod.console_put_char(con, self.x, self.y, self.char, libtcod.BKGND_NONE)

# later...

SCREEN_WIDTH = 80
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 50
player = Object(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, '@', libtcod.yellow)
```

Following a roguelike tutorial and ran into this. Have tried passing an integer by changing the '@' to a number and other things. Have tried handing it to `int(self.char)` and other options but seem to be hitting a wall.

Any help would be great! Tried to include pertinent code, let me know if there's anything else.

EDIT:

```
"""
...
   Args:
    con (Console): Any Console instance.
    x (int): Character x position from the left.
    y (int): Character y position from the top.
    c (Union[int, AnyStr]): Character to draw, can be an integer or string.
    flag (int): Blending mode to use, defaults to BKGND_DEFAULT.
"""
lib.TCOD_console_put_char(_console(con), x, y, _int(c), flag)
```

Comment: Is it possible that `x` and `y` aren't integers? Does doing `int(self.x)` and `int(self.y)` in the function call help?

Comment: I attempted your suggestion which I hadn't thought of it being another arg being the issue but it still did not work. SCREEN_WIDTH = 80 SCREEN_HEIGHT = 50 are whats being passed so they should both be integers.

Comment: Can you post the lines 1230-1236 of the `libtcodpy.py` file? We might be able to tell which parameter is the problem.

Comment: Edited original with those lines. Thanks

Comment: check all arguments which should be integer in this line - `x, y, c, flag`

Comment: 80 / 2 is clearly not an integer.  It's 40.0.  A float.

Comment: Check out http://sscce.org/ and try editing your question is it is complete and minimal.

Comment: @Jean-Paul The SO equivalent of SSCCE is MRE, or [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, dividing two ints always produces a float, so `80/2` and `50/2` are producing floats, not ints. To make them ints, you could either use floor division (`80//2`) or cast to int (`int(80/2)`).

I guess your tutorial is for Python 2, cause in Python 2, dividing two ints always produces an int.

More details

- [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/4518341)
- [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)