# How to fix 'int object is not iterable'

Tags: python

I'm trying to add all the integers in the 'a' variable, but this 'a' variable isn't working as a list nor a string, despite having various different integers in it.

I'm writing a Python program that given a positive integer num, provided by the user, prints the sum of all its divisors. 
I've already tried to make this 'a' variable a list but the same error happens

```
import math
num = int(input("Num: "))
a = num + 1 # because range excludes the last number
b = range(1, a) 
for i in (b):
    x = num / i
    if math.floor(x) == x:
            c = list(i)
```

I've already tried to make this 'a' variable a list but the same error happens: 'int object is not iterable'

Comment: what is `list(i)` supposed to do?

Comment: possible you should use `c = list( range( i ) )` instead of `c = list(i)`

Answer (score 1):

`list()` creates a new list, and its argument must be an iterable (e.g. a tuple, another list, etc.). If you only pass one number, `i`, it won't work.

I suppose what you want to do is *not* to create a new list with each loop iteration, but add the `i` element to an already existing list.
You can achieve it this way:

```
num = int(input("Num: "))
a = num + 1 # because range excludes the last number
b = range(1, a)
divisors = []  # create a new list where the results will be stored
for i in (b):
    x = num / i
    if math.floor(x) == x:
        divisors.append(i)  # add the number at the end of the list
```

If you want to sum all the divisors, use:

```
sum(divisors)
```

An even more 'Pythonic' (though, admittedly, not necessarily easier to read if you're not used to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) way to achieve the same result would be:

```
num = int(input("Num: "))
divisors_sum = sum(i for i in range(1, num + 1) if num//i == num/i)
```

I assume you're using Python 3 here. In Python 3, `//` is floor division, so you don't have to use `math.floor`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) for more details on `//` vs. `/`.

Comment: `c = divisors.append(i)` sets `c` equal to `None`. The `c = ` should be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list outside of the loop: `c = []`, and then each time append an element to the list by `c.append(i)`.

Comment: #1 is not true in Python 3.