# How can I make this algorithm to return whole numbers when division operation is performed?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

This algorithm returns values in floating point numbers. Can anybody suggest the changes required to make it return only whole numbers/values?

```
def zero(f = None): return 0 if not f else f(0)
def one(f = None): return 1 if not f else f(1)
def two(f = None): return 2 if not f else f(2)
def three(f = None): return 3 if not f else f(3)
def four(f = None): return 4 if not f else f(4)
def five(f = None): return 5 if not f else f(5)
def six(f = None): return 6 if not f else f(6)
def seven(f = None): return 7 if not f else f(7)
def eight(f = None): return 8 if not f else f(8)
def nine(f = None): return 9 if not f else f(9)

def plus(y): return lambda x: x+y
def minus(y): return lambda x: x-y
def times(y): return lambda  x: x*y
def divided_by(y): return lambda  x: x/y
```

An example:

```
one(divided_by(four()))
```

This returns 0.25 but I want it to return 0 without using the floor operator.

Comment: `def divided_by(y): return lambda x: x // y`? This is in Python 3, right?

Comment: By "absolute values" do you mean integers? The absolute value of `0.25` is `0.25`, not 0.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thank you for the suggestion but is there any other way?

Comment: What is wrong with that one?

Comment: Nothing wrong. There is a condition in this question where it is not allowed to use the floor division operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use the floor operator, then this should do it:

```
def integer_division(x, y):
    result = 0
    while x >= y:
        x -= y
        result += 1
    return result


def divided_by(y): return lambda x: integer_division(x, y)

print(divided_by(2)(5), divided_by(2)(4), divided_by(3)(9), divided_by(3)(5), divided_by(3)(7))
```

**Output**

```
2 2 3 1 2
```

Or recursively:

```
def integer_division(x, y):
    return 1 + integer_division(x - y, y) if x >= y else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

if you mean for the `absolute value` is the integer part, you can using the integer division instead of the normal division. Such as suggested in comments by @Daniel you can replace `x/y` by `x//y`.

Also, as you have positive numbers, you can use from `numpy.fix` instead. Hence, it would be `numpy.fix(x/y)`.

Comment: Can't use the floor operator. Trying to find another way.