# How to create multiple dataframes with no repetition from one dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
'readings' : ['READ_1','READ_2','READ_1','READ_3','READ_1','READ_5','READ_6','READ_8','READ_10','READ_12','READ_11','READ_14','READ_09','READ_08','READ_07'],
 'val' :[5,6,7,11,5,7,16,12,13,56,32,13,45,43,46],
 })
```

What I would like to do is create multiple dataframes out of this (`df1`,`df2`). In real time it doesn't have to be two. It can be 10 or 20 depending on my data size. **I ask this because i intend to do parallel processing**. I will divide my one huge df to multiple small dataframes and do parallel processing

for example `df1` should contain all the records of 2(two) subjects and `df2` should contain all the records of remaining 2 subjects

Tried this but it isn't right

```
grouped = df.groupby('subject_id')
df1 = grouped.filter(lambda x: x['subject_id']== 2)
```

I expect my output to be like this

**df1** - contains all records of 2 subjects. In real time, I wish to select 100 subjects and would like to have all their records in one dataframe

[image]

**df2** - contains all records of 2 subjects. But in real time, I wish to select 100 subjects and have all their records in one dataframe

[image]

As you can see there is clear segregation of data based on subjects and no presence of data of a subject in multiple dataframe. Like `subject_id = 1 has data only in df1`

**updated post**

[image]

Comment: Both the answers below were good and provides the expected output. I don't know which is best. I can mark only one and go with Jezrael's answer as it had more upvotes. Nonetheless both the answers were upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of DataFrames with `groupby` and

if `subject_id` are numbers from `1` to `N`:

```
dfs = [x for _,x in df.groupby((df['subject_id'] - 1) // N)]
```

General solution working with any values in `subject_id` - e.g. strings:

use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) for array integer divided by number of `subject_id`:

```
N = 2

print (pd.factorize(df['subject_id'])[0])
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]

print (pd.factorize(df['subject_id'])[0] // N )
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
dfs = [x for _,x in df.groupby(pd.factorize(df['subject_id'])[0] // N)]
print (dfs)
[   subject_id readings  val
0           1   READ_1    5
1           1   READ_2    6
2           1   READ_1    7
3           1   READ_3   11
4           2   READ_1    5
5           2   READ_5    7
6           2   READ_6   16
7           2   READ_8   12,     subject_id readings  val
8            3  READ_10   13
9            3  READ_12   56
10           4  READ_11   32
11           4  READ_14   13
12           4  READ_09   45
13           4  READ_08   43
14           4  READ_07   46]
```

---

```
print (dfs[0])
   subject_id readings  val
0           1   READ_1    5
1           1   READ_2    6
2           1   READ_1    7
3           1   READ_3   11
4           2   READ_1    5
5           2   READ_5    7
6           2   READ_6   16
7           2   READ_8   12
```

---

Comment: What's `factorize` for? Why not `[chunk for _, chunk in df.groupby((df['subject_id']-1) // 2)]`

Comment: @Dan - Just added

Comment: Can I know how does `divide by N` works here? `pd.factorize(df['subject_id'])[0] // N `?

Comment: @SSMK - Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/183870) ?

Comment: Thank you. What does this underscore in `x for _,x` imply?

Comment: @SSMK - It is DataFrame by loop `groupby`, `_` is used for not important variable, here it is values from factorize. You can check it `print ([i for i,x in df.groupby(pd.factorize(df['subject_id'])[0] // 2)])` - here is return `0, 1` from sample data, because 2 groups

Comment: Hi Jaezral, Can I check with you whether `N` is just used to indicate the no of resultant dataframes that we would like to create. Am I right? It's not about how many subjects in each group

Comment: It can be 20 or 200 or 2000 based on my requirement. Doesn't have anything to do with the `subject_id`. Am I right? Or `//N` will create a problem?

Comment: Is it possible to do without `dividing`. Because, sometimes my `subject_ids` are like as `12345678`,`234567890`,`55555`,`345678`

Comment: In a case, like this, it all becomes part of the same dataframe.

Comment: @SSMK - It is nomber of unique `subject_id` pre each DataFrame, if number is not integers like `1,2,3,...` then use general solution with `factorize` - it convert your `subject_id` to `0,1,2...` values first

Answer (score 1):

I thin you need [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to make groups:

```
n=2
groups=pd.cut(df['subject_id'],n)
for i , group in df.groupby(groups):
    print(group)

   subject_id readings  val
0           1   READ_1    5
1           1   READ_2    6
2           1   READ_1    7
3           1   READ_3   11
4           2   READ_1    5
5           2   READ_5    7
6           2   READ_6   16
7           2   READ_8   12
    subject_id readings  val
8            3  READ_10   13
9            3  READ_12   56
10           4  READ_11   32
11           4  READ_14   13
12           4  READ_09   45
13           4  READ_08   43
14           4  READ_07   46
```

---

If you want you can save in a list:

```
#savig in a list
df_list=[group for i , group in df.groupby(groups)]
```