# Why is python defaulting to floor division when I only use one slash?

Tags: python, python-2.7, division

When I type regular division, it defaults to floor. Why is it doing this? How do I change it? Will I have to change it every time?

ex:

```
>>>97/20
4 
>>>97//20
4
```

Comment: 97/20.0 will solve the problem

Comment: You almost certainly should be using Python 3 instead of Python 2, btw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)

Answer (score 3):

That's because both numbers are integers, and in Python 2 it works that way: dividing two integers uses floor division. You could see a difference if you did this:

```
>>>97.0/20.0
4.85
>>>97.0//20.0
4.0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using python 2.x, this is not the problem with python 3.x

If you want to get precise result use 97/20.0.

Adding 20.0 will do the type casting of the result to float

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Answer (score 2):

You’re using Python2. The behaviour when dividing integers  changed to float division by default in  Python3. So if you want float division by default for integers use Python3 or place

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your code to use that feature.

In fact, there are many reasons why it’s probably better for you start using Python3 right away.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division