# What does this line do? i dont get it

Tags: python

i do not understand the third line at all, i tried researching in different places i cant seem to find it anywhere. I know what the len function do, but i do not understand the numbers and the division part of this code. What this code does is returning the middle part of each words.

```
def middle_char(txt):

    return txt[(len(txt)-1)//2:(len(txt)+2)//2]  

print(middle_char("Python"))
print(middle_char("PHP"))
print(middle_char("Java"))
```

Answer (score 2):

So:

```
return txt[(len(txt)-1)//2:(len(txt)+2)//2]
```

Going from inner to outer:

```
len(txt)
```

If `txt` has a length, `len` returns that value. For strings, that's the number of characters.

```
len(txt)-1
```

Calculate the number of characters in `txt` and subtract `1` from that value.

```
(len(txt)-1)//2
```

`//` is [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division). The objective here is to ensure the value is not fractional (this is important, since we'll use it as an index for the character sequence in `txt`).

Given some list `l`, `l[a:b]` is a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) that returns all elements between indices `a` and `b` (not inclusive of `b`, so `[a, b)`).

The outcome this code should produce is to calculate the indices of the midpoint of the string and return that slice (one character for odd-numbered sequences, two for even-numbered).

Comment: Looks like it returns the single middle character for odd-length strings, the middle two characters for even-length strings.