# What is the meaning of operator // when checking palindrome number in python

Tags: python, palindrome

So i got this code to check if a number is a palindrome and it works fine but i got a question on the usage of some operator in the `while` loop. The operator `//` that is used between the original variable and integer `10`. What is it doing to the original `p` value , is it dividing or? Here is the code am using

```
def test_palindrome(p):
    o=p#store the original value of p in some variable
    reversed_number=0#declare reversed_number and init to zero
    while(p>0):
        rem=p%10#Get the remainder of argument and ten
        reversed_number=reversed_number*10+rem
        p=p//10#This is the operator whose function is in question, am not sure if its dividing
    if(reversed_number==o):#do comparison with original input and return 
        print(f"{o} is a palindrome")
    else:
        print(f"{o} is not a palindrome")
test_palindrome(number)
```

Comment: `5 / 2 = 2.5` but `5 // 2 = 2`

Comment: Yeah it does thanks, grabbing code online is a nightmare but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` means floor division. Floor division will always give you the integer floor of the result

Your program first starts with checking if `p>0`. Lets say `p = 1001`.

`1001 // 10 = 100` whereas `1001/10 = 100.1`

If you used `p/10` instead of `p//10`. `p` would never be less than `0`. A decimal: `0.1` (example) would always exist. Therefore, the conditon `p>0` would always be true, breaking your program.

---

As mentioned in the comments, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division) post may be of use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i was just wondering what the operator means

Comment: @CoderTimothy No problem, thought it would be of use to include what it means in terms of your program as well.