# Why is the result of this division returning a integer not a float?

Tags: python, dictionary, division

I'm trying to do a division operation between two `dict` and I'm always getting an `int` result, but I expected a `float`.

Here is what is going on:

```py
test_dict1 = {'gfg': 20, 'is': 24, 'best': 30}
test_dict2 = {'gfg': 7, 'is': 7, 'best': 7}

res = {key: test_dict1[key] // test_dict2.get(key, 0)
       for key in test_dict1.keys()}

res = {'best': 4, 'gfg': 2, 'is': 3}
```

Comment: See [// floor division](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-floor-division/)

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You used integer division; why do you expect something other than the documented return type?

Comment: I don't think he knew that `//` was integer division / quotient / floor function... I don't suspect this is a case of malice. That being said, he probably should have looked elsewhere before posting. @prune

Comment: The issue is not malice, but whether the question belongs in the SO archives.  The intro tour clearly states the expected research.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your operator: `//`. The `//` operator in python returns the quotient from a division. Taking the 'best' key as an example, 30 // 7 => 4Q, 2R. What you are looking for is simply the `/` operator. `30/7 = 4.285.....`

Corrected:

```
res = {
    key: test_dict1[key] / test_dict2.get(key, 0) for key in test_dict1.keys()
}
```