# Finding the LCM of a range of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, lcm

I read an interesting DailyWTF post today, ["Out of All The Possible Answers..."](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Out-of-All-the-Possible-Answers.aspx) and it interested me enough to dig up the original [forum post](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/10030.aspx) where it was submitted. This got me thinking how I would solve this interesting problem - the original question is posed on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=5) as:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the 
>   numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest number that is evenly divisible by all of 
>   the numbers from 1 to 20?

To reform this as a programming question, **how would you create a function that can find the Least Common Multiple for an arbitrary list of numbers?**

I'm incredibly bad with pure math, despite my interest in programming, but I was able to solve this after a little Googling and some experimenting. I'm curious what other approaches SO users might take. If you're so inclined, post some code below, hopefully along with an explanation. Note that while I'm sure libraries exist to compute the GCD and LCM in various languages, I'm more interested in something that displays the logic more directly than calling a library function :-)

I'm most familiar with Python, C,  C++, and Perl, but any language you prefer is welcome. Bonus points for explaining the logic for other mathematically-challenged folks out there like myself.

**EDIT**: After submitting I did find this similar question [Least common multiple for 3 or more numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147515) but it was answered with the same basic code I already figured out and there's no real explanation, so I felt this was different enough to leave open.

Comment: btw - is the answer 10581480? I believe it to be the right answer for the particular problem :)

Comment: @warren - I was freaked out by your answer, as for a while I thought you were right (only just found this question), and the lcm calculator I wrote in Haskell was giving a wildly different answer, and 10581480 seemed to be divisible by [1..20]. I must have made a mistake somewhere as your answer is not evenly divisible by 11 or 16. The correct answer is 232792560.

Comment: @Matt Ellen - good call, not sure how I missed 11 in my answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem is interesting because it doesn't require you to find the LCM of an arbitrary set of numbers, you're given a consecutive range.  You can use a variation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find the answer.

```
def RangeLCM(first, last):
    factors = range(first, last+1)
    for i in range(0, len(factors)):
        if factors[i] != 1:
            n = first + i
            for j in range(2*n, last+1, n):
                factors[j-first] = factors[j-first] / factors[i]
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, factors, 1)
```

---

Edit: A recent upvote made me re-examine this answer which is over 3 years old. My first observation is that I would have written it a little differently today, using `enumerate` for example. A couple of small changes were necessary to make it compatible with Python 3.

The second observation is that this algorithm only works if the start of the range is 2 or less, because it doesn't try to sieve out the common factors below the start of the range. For example, RangeLCM(10, 12) returns 1320 instead of the correct 660.

The third observation is that nobody attempted to time this answer against any other answers. My gut said that this would improve over a brute force LCM solution as the range got larger. Testing proved my gut correct, at least this once.

Since the algorithm doesn't work for arbitrary ranges, I rewrote it to assume that the range starts at 1. I removed the call to `reduce` at the end, as it was easier to compute the result as the factors were generated. I believe the new version of the function is both more correct and easier to understand.

```
def RangeLCM2(last):
    factors = list(range(last+1))
    result = 1
    for n in range(last+1):
        if factors[n] > 1:
            result *= factors[n]
            for j in range(2*n, last+1, n):
                factors[j] //= factors[n]
    return result
```

Here are some timing comparisons against the original and the solution proposed by [Joe Bebel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196472/5987) which is called `RangeEuclid` in my tests.

```
>>> t=timeit.timeit
>>> t('RangeLCM.RangeLCM(1, 20)', 'import RangeLCM')
17.999292996735676
>>> t('RangeLCM.RangeEuclid(1, 20)', 'import RangeLCM')
11.199833288867922
>>> t('RangeLCM.RangeLCM2(20)', 'import RangeLCM')
14.256165588084514
>>> t('RangeLCM.RangeLCM(1, 100)', 'import RangeLCM')
93.34979585394194
>>> t('RangeLCM.RangeEuclid(1, 100)', 'import RangeLCM')
109.25695507389901
>>> t('RangeLCM.RangeLCM2(100)', 'import RangeLCM')
66.09684505991709
```

For the range of 1 to 20 given in the question, Euclid's algorithm beats out both my old and new answers. For the range of 1 to 100 you can see the sieve-based algorithm pull ahead, especially the optimized version.

Comment: thanks Mark! this is exactly the kind of interesting reply I had in mind :-)

Comment: that is quite clever - I hadn't thought about it that way :)

Answer (score 20):

The answer does not require any fancy footwork at all in terms of factoring or prime powers, and most certainly does not require the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Instead, you should calculate the LCM of a single pair by computing the GCD using Euclid's algorithm (which does NOT require factorization, and in fact is significantly faster):

```
def lcm(a,b):
    gcd, tmp = a,b
    while tmp != 0:
        gcd,tmp = tmp, gcd % tmp
    return a*b/gcd
```

then you can find the total LCM my reducing the array using the above lcm() function:

```
reduce(lcm, range(1,21))
```

Comment: Indeed, that's the same algorithm I ended up with, and also what was provided as the solution to the similar question. Seems to be the general consensus on how to solve this.

Comment: Use return a*(b/gcd) or return (a/gcd)*b. Because a*b can be a large number.

Answer (score 10):

There's a fast solution to this, so long as the range is 1 to N.

The key observation is that if `n` (< N) has prime factorization  `p_1^a_1 * p_2^a_2 * ... p_k * a_k`, 
then it will contribute exactly the same factors to the LCM as `p_1^a_1` and `p_2^a_2`, ... `p_k^a_k`. And each of these powers is also in the 1 to N range. Thus we only need to consider the highest pure prime powers less than N.

For example for 20 we have

```
2^4 = 16 < 20
3^2 = 9  < 20
5^1 = 5  < 20
7
11
13
17
19
```

Multiplying all these prime powers together we get the required result of

```
2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*11*13*17*19 = 232792560
```

So in pseudo code:

```
def lcm_upto(N):
  total = 1;
  foreach p in primes_less_than(N):
    x=1;
    while x*p <= N:
      x=x*p;
    total = total * x
  return total
```

Now you can tweak the inner loop to work slightly differently to get more speed, and you can precalculate the `primes_less_than(N)` function.

EDIT:

Due to a recent upvote I decideded to revisit this, to see how the speed comparison with the other listed algorithms went.

Timing for range 1-160 with 10k iterations, against Joe Beibers and Mark Ransoms methods are as follows:

Joes  : 1.85s
Marks : 3.26s
Mine  : 0.33s

Here's a log-log graph with the results up to 300.

[image: A log-log graph with the results]

Code for my test can be found here:

```
import timeit


def RangeLCM2(last):
    factors = range(last+1)
    result = 1
    for n in range(last+1):
        if factors[n] > 1:
            result *= factors[n]
            for j in range(2*n, last+1, n):
                factors[j] /= factors[n]
    return result


def lcm(a,b):
    gcd, tmp = a,b
    while tmp != 0:
        gcd,tmp = tmp, gcd % tmp
    return a*b/gcd

def EuclidLCM(last):
    return reduce(lcm,range(1,last+1))

primes = [
 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 
 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 
 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 
 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 
 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 
 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 
 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 
 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 
 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 
 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 
 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 
 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 
 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 
 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 
 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 
 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 
 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997 ]

def FastRangeLCM(last):
    total = 1
    for p in primes:
        if p>last:
            break
        x = 1
        while x*p <= last:
            x = x * p
        total = total * x
    return total


print RangeLCM2(20)
print EculidLCM(20)
print FastRangeLCM(20)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(20)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(20)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(20)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(40)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(40)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(40)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(60)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(60)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(60)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(80)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(80)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(80)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(100)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(100)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(100)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(120)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(120)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(120)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(140)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(140)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(140)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)

print timeit.Timer( 'RangeLCM2(160)', "from __main__ import RangeLCM2").timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'EuclidLCM(160)', "from __main__ import EuclidLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
print timeit.Timer( 'FastRangeLCM(160)', "from __main__ import FastRangeLCM" ).timeit(number=10000)
```

Comment: Instead of that lengthy list of primes<1000, you can say  `primes = [2,3]+[x for x in range(5,1000,2) if pow(3,x-1,x)==1==pow(2,x-1,x)]` which executes in less than a millisecond.

Comment: @Michael What algorithm did you use to find the primes ?

Comment: @tilaprimera I think I just copied them from a list of primes. But there are many quick algorithms for computing primes that you can find on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into Sieve of eratosthenes

Answer (score 5):

One-liner in Haskell.

```
wideLCM = foldl lcm 1
```

This is what I used for my own Project Euler Problem 5.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell:

```
listLCM xs =  foldr (lcm) 1 xs
```

Which you can pass a list eg:

```
*Main> listLCM [1..10]
2520
*Main> listLCM [1..2518]
266595767785593803705412270464676976610857635334657316692669925537787454299898002207461915073508683963382517039456477669596355816643394386272505301040799324518447104528530927421506143709593427822789725553843015805207718967822166927846212504932185912903133106741373264004097225277236671818323343067283663297403663465952182060840140577104161874701374415384744438137266768019899449317336711720217025025587401208623105738783129308128750455016347481252967252000274360749033444720740958140380022607152873903454009665680092965785710950056851148623283267844109400949097830399398928766093150813869944897207026562740359330773453263501671059198376156051049807365826551680239328345262351788257964260307551699951892369982392731547941790155541082267235224332660060039217194224518623199770191736740074323689475195782613618695976005218868557150389117325747888623795360149879033894667051583457539872594336939497053549704686823966843769912686273810907202177232140876251886218209049469761186661055766628477277347438364188994340512556761831159033404181677107900519850780882430019800537370374545134183233280000
```

Answer (score 2):

The LCM of one or more numbers is the product of all of the distinct prime factors in all of the numbers, each prime to the power of the max of all the powers to which that prime appears in the numbers one is taking the LCM of.

Say 900 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5^2, 26460 = 2^2 * 3^3 * 5^1 * 7^2.
The max power of 2 is 3, the max power of 3 is 3, the max power of 5 is 1, the max power of 7 is 2, and the max power of any higher prime is 0.
So the LCM is: 264600 = 2^3 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7^2.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it looks like you and Warren provided the same basic answer. I was hoping people would post samples showing different approaches to solving this in code, it'd be great if you could post an algorithmic approach using this techqnique!

Answer (score 2):

```
print "LCM of 4 and 5 = ".LCM(4,5)."\n";

sub LCM {
    my ($a,$b) = @_;    
    my ($af,$bf) = (1,1);   # The factors to apply to a & b

    # Loop and increase until A times its factor equals B times its factor
    while ($a*$af != $b*$bf) {
        if ($a*$af>$b*$bf) {$bf++} else {$af++};
    }
    return $a*$af;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm in Haskell. This is the language I think in nowadays for algorithmic thinking. This might seem strange, complicated, and uninviting -- welcome to Haskell!

```
primes :: (Integral a) => [a]
--implementation of primes is to be left for another day.

primeFactors :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
primeFactors n = go n primes where
    go n ps@(p : pt) =
        if q < 1 then [] else
        if r == 0 then p : go q ps else
        go n pt
        where (q, r) = quotRem n p

multiFactors :: (Integral a) => a -> [(a, Int)]
multiFactors n = [ (head xs, length xs) | xs <- group $ primeFactors $ n ]

multiProduct :: (Integral a) => [(a, Int)] -> a
multiProduct xs = product $ map (uncurry (^)) $ xs

mergeFactorsPairwise [] bs = bs
mergeFactorsPairwise as [] = as
mergeFactorsPairwise a@((an, am) : _) b@((bn, bm) : _) =
    case compare an bn of
        LT -> (head a) : mergeFactorsPairwise (tail a) b
        GT -> (head b) : mergeFactorsPairwise a (tail b)
        EQ -> (an, max am bm) : mergeFactorsPairwise (tail a) (tail b)

wideLCM :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a
wideLCM nums = multiProduct $ foldl mergeFactorsPairwise [] $ map multiFactors $ nums
```

Comment: I think you've over engineered it

Comment: I already had primeFactors, multiFactors, and multiProduct written for some other purposes (mathematical interest, mostly). The other two functions weren't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Python stab at it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import mul

def factor(n):
    factors = {}
    i = 2 
    while i <= n and n != 1:
        while n % i == 0:
            try:
                factors[i] += 1
            except KeyError:
                factors[i] = 1
            n = n / i
        i += 1
    return factors

base = {}
for i in range(2, 2000):
    for f, n in factor(i).items():
        try:
            base[f] = max(base[f], n)
        except KeyError:
            base[f] = n

print reduce(mul, [f**n for f, n in base.items()], 1)
```

Step one gets the prime factors of a number.  Step two builds a hash table of the maximum number of times each factor was seen, then multiplies them all together.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the cleanest, shortest answer (both in terms of lines of code) that I've seen so far.

```
def gcd(a,b): return b and gcd(b, a % b) or a
def lcm(a,b): return a * b / gcd(a,b)

n = 1
for i in xrange(1, 21):
    n = lcm(n, i)
```

source : http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer in JavaScript.   I first approached this from primes, and developed a nice function of reusable code to find primes and also to find prime factors, but in the end decided that this approach was simpler.

There's nothing unique in my answer that's not posted above, it's just in Javascript which I did not see specifically.

```
//least common multipe of a range of numbers
function smallestCommons(arr) {
   arr = arr.sort();
   var scm = 1; 
   for (var i = arr[0]; i<=arr[1]; i+=1) { 
        scm =  scd(scm, i); 
    }
  return scm;
}


//smallest common denominator of two numbers (scd)
function scd (a,b) {
     return a*b/gcd(a,b);
}


//greatest common denominator of two numbers (gcd)
function gcd(a, b) {
    if (b === 0) {  
        return a;
    } else {
       return gcd(b, a%b);
    }
}       

smallestCommons([1,20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my javascript solution, I hope you find it easy to follow:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
  var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

  var smallestCommon = min * max;

  var doneCalc = 0;

  while (doneCalc === 0) {
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      if (smallestCommon % i !== 0) {
        smallestCommon += max;
        doneCalc = 0;
        break;
      }
      else {
        doneCalc = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return smallestCommon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using C Lang

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int a,b,lcm=1,small,gcd=1,done=0,i,j,large=1,div=0;
    printf("Enter range\n");
    printf("From:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("To:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int n=b-a+1;
    int num[30];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        num[i]=a+i;
    }
    //Finds LCM
    while(!done){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(num[i]==1){
                done=1;continue;
            }
            done=0;
            break;
        }
        if(done){
            continue;
        }
        done=0;
        large=1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(num[i]>large){
                large=num[i];
            }
        }
        div=0;
        for(i=2;i<=large;i++){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(num[j]%i==0){
                    num[j]/=i;div=1;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if(div){
                lcm*=i;div=0;break;
            }
        }
    }
    done=0;
    //Finds GCD
    while(!done){
        small=num[0];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(num[i]<small){
                small=num[i];
            }
        }
        div=0;
        for(i=2;i<=small;i++){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(num[j]%i==0){
                    div=1;continue;
                }
                div=0;break;
            }
            if(div){
                for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                    num[j]/=i;
                }
                gcd*=i;div=0;break;
            }
        }
        if(i==small+1){
            done=1;
        }
    }
    printf("LCM = %d\n",lcm);
    printf("GCD = %d\n",gcd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In expanding on @Alexander's comment, I'd point out that if you can factor the numbers to their primes, remove duplicates, then multiply-out, you'll have your answer.

For example, 1-5 have the prime factors of 2,3,2,2,5. Remove the duplicated '2' from the factor list of the '4', and you have 2,2,3,5. Multiplying those together yields 60, which is your answer.

The Wolfram link provided in the previous comment, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastCommonMultiple.html goes into a much more formal approach, but the short version is above.

Cheers.

Comment: Unclear what "remove duplicates" mean. You're removing the '2' from the 2 because it's captured by the factorization of the 4. That's not just semantics. 

Justice puts it a little better. . .you want to take just the value of  the MAX power of each prime. Then, you know lower powers are factors.