# Program using loops for math purpose. (Java)

Tags: java, loops, math, conditional-statements

Let me explain the problem.

I need to write a program where I enter a number N and, then I must find the minimum number divisible by all the numbers down to one.

Eg:. If my N is 5, the answer would be 60. 60 is divisible by 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1.

Here is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questão_04 {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int x = 1, n = 1, d = x % n;

    System.out.print("Enter N: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    n = in.nextInt();

    do
    {
        if (d != 0)
        {
            x = x + 1;
            do
            {
                n = n -1;                   
            } while (n != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                n = n - 1;
            } while (d != 0);
        }

    } while (n != 0);

    System.out.print(x);\\the minimum number divisible by N and all up to N.

}
```

Comment: ok, I've finally found a correct and pretty efficient answer. great question btw. took me some time ^^

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after racking my brain for some time, i finally found an efficient solution:

```
public int smallestMatching(int n){
    ArrayList<Integer> divisors = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++){
        int tmp = i;

        //simplify div, until it can't be created by multiplying elements of divisors
        for(int div : divisors)
            if(tmp % div == 0)
                tmp /= div;

        if(tmp != 1) 
        //tmp cant be generated from number that are content of divisors
        //-> add to divisors
        {
            divisors.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    //calculate the final result
    int result = 1;
    for(int div: divisors)
        result *= div;

    return result;
}
```

Love that question :D.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient algorithm for finding this value considers only the prime powers less than or equal to N.

- start with `v = 1`
- for `p_i` in primes less than or equal to `N`

  - find maximum integer `q_i` such that `p_i ^ q_i <= N`
  - `v *= p_i ^ q_i`

For you example N=5, the primes are 2,3,5 and

- 2^2 = 4 < 5 < 2^3
- 3^1 = 3 < 5 < 3^3
- 5^1 = 5 = 5 < 5^2

So v = 2^2 * 3 * 5 = 60

For N = 18, you end up with

v = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17

The only tricky bit is the generation of the primes less than N.

However since v grows very quickly as N increases ( `O(N!)` or `O(N^log(N))` or something like that) you will overflow integer (or even long) arithmetic, at some low value of N (in the hundreds maybe?) This means you can probably get away with precalculating a small table of primes. (Unless you're using an arbitrary precision numerical type)

Comment: actually the code is far more efficient, shorter and needs less tables, if you generate the primes on the run (i've tried both solutions).

Comment: I knew I'd answered something like this before: Here's a previous answer with a bit more info (in python though...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185781/finding-the-lcm-of-a-range-of-numbers/10648539#10648539

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to calculate `f(n) = lcm(1,2,...,n)`. The function seems to grow rapidly for small `n`, though it may eventually taper off as the primes space out, I suppose. Theory says `ln f(n)/n` is asymptotic to `1`, so `f(n)` grows roughly exponentially.

We can simplify by noting `lcm(1,2,...,n)` = `lcm(lcm(1,2,...,n-1),n)`, so `f(n)` can be computed recursively. Furthermore, `lcm(a,b) = a*b/gcd(a,b)` so we can write the recursion in terms of the standard `gcd` function. I suggest calculating `f` recursively as follows: `f(n+1) = f(n) / gcd(f(n),n+1) * (n+1)`. Dividing before multiplying keeps the size of intermediate results small. The `gcd` divides `f(n)` evenly so integer division is fine. You can speed up the calculation by memoizing the `f(n)` though it won't help if you're only calculating `f(n)` for one `n`.

I've implemented the function in Java below. It runs as fast as I can hit , at least until stack size overflows, around `n=10000` on my computer. You can reorganize to use iteration instead of recursion, which might push the maximum `n` higher. (I guess it runs out of memory around `n=50000` on my computer based on similar situations, but I haven't actually tried it.)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class LCM {
  public static BigInteger f(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger prev = f(n-1);
    return prev.divide(prev.gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(n)))
      .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println("f(" + n + ") = " + f(n));
  }
}
```