# I turn some Python codes into R format, but the output is different

Tags: python, r

I'm working on [problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) of Project Euler. I'm trying to convert another user's Python code into R, but the output is different.

The Python script's output is `232792560`, where's the R script's output is `1964187225`

Where is the error?

Python code:

```py
def is_prime(number):
    for n in range(2, number):
        if number % n != 0:
            n += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True


def smallest_multiple(num):
    exp = 1
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, num):
        if is_prime(i):
            while True:
                if i**exp > num:
                    result *= i**(exp-1)
                    break
                exp += 1
            exp = 1
    return result

print(smallest_multiple(20))
```

R code:

```r
is_prime <- function(num) {
  for (n in seq(2, num)) {
    if (num %% n != 0) {
      n <- n + 1
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
    return(TRUE)
  }
}

lcm <- function(num) {
  exp <- 1
  result <- 1
  for (i in seq(2, num)) {
    if (is_prime(i)) {
      while (TRUE) {
        if (i ^ exp > num) {
          result <- result * i ^ (exp - 1)
          break
        }
        exp <- exp + 1
      }
      exp <- 1
    }
  }
  return(result)
}
lcm(20)
```

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024911/project-euler-5-in-python-how-can-i-optimize-my-solution) and [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/project-euler-problem-5/). It is how the R interpreter is different from python. It is pretty intuitive

Comment: As per your R code, 2 is not prime.

Comment: seq(2, num) runs from 2 to num while range(2, num) runs from 2 to (num-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your solution.

First, `seq` in R includes the endpoint; `range` in Python does not. Furthermore, `range(2, 1)` in Python is an empty range, whereas `seq(2, 1)` in R produces the result `2 1`. Therefore, it is necessary to modify your R `is_prime` function to check explicitly if the input is 2.

Second, your `is_prime` function in R has `return (TRUE)` in the `for` loop, when it should be outside (a number is prime only if it is not divisible by any number less than it).

This will work:

```
is_prime <- function(num) {
  if (num == 2){
    return(TRUE)
  }
  for (n in seq(2, num - 1)) {
    if (num %% n == 0) {
      return(FALSE)
    } 
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

lcm <- function(num) {
  exp <- 1
  result <- 1
  for (i in seq(2, num - 1)) {
    if (is_prime(i)) {
      while (TRUE) {
        if (i ^ exp > num) {
          result <- result * i ^ (exp - 1)
          break
        }
        exp <- exp + 1
      }
      exp <- 1
    }
  }
  return(result)
}
lcm(20)
```

Output:

```
232792560
```

There are other weird things about your code; for example, you do not need to add 1 to `n` manually, you only have to check up to the square root of `n`, and even numbers are immediately out. Nevertheless, these are more questions of efficiency than correctness.