# Simplify a Fraction

Tags: php

How can I simplify a fraction in PHP?

For instance, converting `40/100` to `2/5`.

The only way I could think of is to do a prime factorization on both numbers and compare like results, but I'm not really sure how to do that either.

Comment: How about this function https://web.archive.org/web/20140205194809/http://forrst.com/posts/PHP_simplify_fraction-9rg

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you simplify a fraction, you divide the numerator and denominator by their greatest common divisor.

So all you need is to calcuate the GCD of the two numbers. There's no built-in function for that, but it's easy enough to implement the [euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclids_algorithm):

```
function gcd($a,$b) {
    $a = abs($a); $b = abs($b);
    if( $a < $b) list($b,$a) = Array($a,$b);
    if( $b == 0) return $a;
    $r = $a % $b;
    while($r > 0) {
        $a = $b;
        $b = $r;
        $r = $a % $b;
    }
    return $b;
}
```

Then just divide the top and bottom by that.

```
function simplify($num,$den) {
    $g = gcd($num,$den);
    return Array($num/$g,$den/$g);
}
var_export(simplify(40,100)); // Array(2,5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple recursive  PHP function

```php
<?php

  function reduceFraction($numerator, $denominator)
  {
    $gcd = findGreatestCommonDenominator($numerator, $denominator);

    return [$numerator / $gcd, $denominator / $gcd];
  }


  function findGreatestCommonDenominator($a, $b)
  {
    return $b ? findGreatestCommonDenominator($b, $a % $b) : $a;
  }
}
```

usage :

```php
<?php $reduced = reduceFraction(40,100); // returns [2,5] ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have  PHP `gmp` extension, you can do this.

```
$num = 40;
$den = 100;
$gcd = gmp_intval(gmp_gcd((string)$num, (string)$den));

$new_num = $num / $gcd;
$new_den = $den / $gcd;
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is pretty simple:

- extract both values from a string.
- find their greatest common divisor ($gcd) (with [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), for example)
- divide both values by $gcd
- rebuild the string with the values found