# Convert Fractions to Words

Tags: php, fractions

I'd like to know if there is a neat way to convert `1/2, 1/4, 5/8` into words (`half, quarter, five eighths`) using PHP.

I've got a product data feed, and need to create a clean URL for each product based on the name. Some have measurements like 1/4" and currently I swap out any non letter/numbers leaving me with "14" in this case. It would be more useful to convert this fraction into "quarter".

Comment: A little more context perhaps? For eg. you need to replace them in a paragraph, or from some answer you get after calculations etc.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question to explain what I am doing with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no neat way to do this.

You'll need to

- Implement an [int-to-cardinal-string](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/) converter for the numerators
- Modify this into an int-to-ordinal-string converter for the denominators ("third" instead of "three" etc. without also making "twenty-three" into "twentieth third")
- Add some special cases ("second" -> "half", "fourth" -> "quarter" if you're not American... "first" -> ""?)
- Optionally implement a [simplifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412782/simplify-a-fraction) so "2/4" => "half" not "two quarters"
- Don't forget to pluralize your denominator if necessary!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print `two by five`, `one by four` etc, I have a way.

1. explode your number by "/". `$nums= explode("/",$num)`
2. Use [function](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/) in this link to convert digit to number,

> $ones= convert_number_to_words($nums[0]);

```
$two=  convert_number_to_words($nums[1]);
```

Then, `echo $ones."by".$two`; Output.

Comment: That does not give 'half' and 'quarter'

Comment: This is what I was thinking about. I'd probably match [\d]\/[\d] and then split the numbers on the / and then work out how to add "th" and "nd" based on the last digit of the denominator.

Comment: @Tuim I said it on first sentence. Since he needs to clean his url, I hope this fits.

Comment: It's sort of in the right direction, but doesn't give me the denominators that I need. (thirds / fifths, nineteenths)