# How can I identify the column with the greatest average in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following array:

```
    complete_matrix = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2, 4],
    [1, 0, 3, 5],
    [2, 3, 0, 6]])
```

I would like to identify the column with the highest average, excluding the diagonal zeros. So, in this case, I would be able to identify complete_matrix[:,3] as being the column with the highest average.

Comment: I [added this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17420604/832621) the takes into account the exclusion of the diagonal of zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this question different from the one here: [Finding the row with the highest average in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395516/finding-the-row-with-the-highest-average-in-a-numpy-array)

As far as I understand, the only difference is the matrix in this post isn't a square matrix. In case this was deliberate, you could try using weights. Since I do not understand your intent fully, the following solution assigns 0 weight to zero entries, 1 otherwise:

```
numpy.argmax(numpy.average(complete_matrix,axis=0, weights=complete_matrix!=0))
```

You can always create a weight matrix where the weight is 0 for diagonal entries, and 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
import numpy

complete_matrix = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2, 4],
    [1, 0, 3, 5],
    [2, 3, 0, 6]])

print complete_matrix[:,numpy.argmax(numpy.mean(complete_matrix, 0))]
# [4 5 6]
```