# function returning the smallest difference between elements of two lists - python

Tags: python, function

Let's say `a` and `b` are recorded at a constant rate of 2s and 3s respectively:

```
>>> a
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12
>>> b
0, 3, 6, 9, 12
```

I'd like to write a function in python that returns

1. the smallest positive difference (i.e., bigger than zero) of `a-b`, and
2. the number of instances that takes `b` to reach the same value of `a`.

So in the previous example,

1. the smallest difference of `a-b` is 1, that is, when `a==4` and `b==3` (or `a==10` and `b==9`)
2. it takes 3 instances of `b` to reach the same value of `a` (i.e., `0, 3, 6`).

Ideally I'd like to use the function in this manner:

```
a = 2
b = 3
>>> my_fun(a,b)
>>> [1, 3] #1-smallest difference, 3-number of instances
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: @tcaswell: I thought of looping through every element of a and b and calculate the difference, but I'm sure there must be a more efficient way of doing this...

Comment: If the values are random, there really isn't a better way. Are they monotonically increasing? Random?

Comment: @Max: They are not random, they are increasing in steps defined by a and b. If a is 2.34 then [0, 2.34, 4.68, etc]

Comment: if a/b is irrational, you will never have the same value in both.

Comment: @tcaswell: That's a good point. You're right a/b must not be irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def worker(a, b):
    i, j, k = a, b, a
    while a != b:
        if a < b:
            a += i
        else:
            n = a - b
            k = n if not k else min(k, n)
            b += j

    return k, b / j + 1

>>> worker(4, 4)
(4, 2)
>>> worker(2, 3)
(1, 3)
```

Comment: `<>` has been deprecated, use `!=`. That's what happens when you use lot of sql ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `lcm()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147539/505154):

```
def my_fun(a, b):
    n = lcm(a, b)
    arange = range(0, n+1, n // a if n > a else a)
    brange = range(0, n+1, n // b if n > b else b)
    m = min(x - y for x in arange for y in brange if x > y)
    return [m, n//b + 1]
```

This is assuming your values `a` and `b` are integers, if you need to do this for floats just multiply by some power of 10 to make them ints.  So for example with `a=2.34` and `b=3.73` you would multiply by 100, run `my_fun(234, 373)`, and then divide the first value of the result by 100 (the second value can be used as is).

Here is the `lcm()` function and `gcd()` function that it depends on:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm."""
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Return lowest common multiple."""
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)
```

Comment: .: Thanks! However, if I run my_fun(4,4) I get [1,2]. In this case the smallest difference is actually 4, but the function is returning 1...

Comment: In fact, the function is always returning 1 as the smallest difference, no matter which values a and b have.

Comment: @HappyPy check my solution, if you have more test cases

Comment: See my edit, I think the issue with the differences should be resolved.