# Find lowest common multiple of many datetime.timedelta objects

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, lcm

Given a list of `n` timedelta objects, with the lowest denomination of time being minutes,

```
from datetime import timedelta as td

[td(days=1, hours=4, minutes=0),
 td(days=0, hours=2 minutes=30),
 td(days=3, hours=0 minutes=30),
 ...]
```

how can I find the lowest common multiple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert it all to seconds and get the LCM. Use `timedelta.total_seconds()`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks. I used the second answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147515/least-common-multiple-for-3-or-more-numbers to find the LCM of the total seconds in case anybody looks for that.