# How to find lcm of multiple numbers using GCD approach?

Tags: algorithm, function, lcm

I'm using the euclidean approach i.e  LCM = num1 * num2 /  gcd ( num1 , num2 )
I have sucessfully made the code for two numbers but it is buggy if i try it for multiple inputs.
my approach can be represented as
lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(a,lcm(b,c))
but this approach does not work as they(lcm(a,b,c)and lcm(a,lcm(b,c))) are two different values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Least common multiple for 3 or more numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147515/least-common-multiple-for-3-or-more-numbers)

Comment: Your approach should work. If it does not, you have a bug in your implementation, in which case you should post your code if you can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Perhaps your intermediate numbers are overflowing the datatype?

Comment: Have you tried: `LCM = num1  / gcd ( num1 , num2 ) * num2` instead, to avoid overflow?

Answer (score 0):

**I compute LCM by Sieves of Eratosthenes like this in C++:**

```
int lcm(int *a,int N,bool _sorted=false)    // least common multiple of a[N]
    {                                       // if sorted a[N] must be: (a0 > a1 > a2 > ... > aN)
    if (N<1) return 0;
    int i,j,c,dc;
    int *b=new int[N];
    if (_sorted) for (i=0;i<N;i++) b[i]=a[i];   // b[N] = a[N]
    else for (c=0x7FFFFFFF,j=0;j<N;j++,c=dc)    // b[N] = insert sort a[N]
        {
        for (dc=0,i=0;i<N;i++)
         if ((dc<a[i])&&(c>a[i])) dc=a[i];
        if (!dc) { N=j; break; }
        b[j]=dc;
        }
    // replace duplicit multiplies with 1
    for (i=  0;i<N;i++) if (b[i]>1)
    for (j=i+1;j<N;j++) if (b[j]>1)
     if (b[i]%b[j]==0) b[j]=1;
    // cut off all ones
    for (j=0,i=0;i<N;i++) if (b[i]>1) { b[j]=b[i]; j++; } N=j;
    if (N<1) return 1;
    // lcm
    for (dc=b[0],i=-1,c=dc;i<0;c+=dc)
     for (i=1;i<N;i++)
      if (c%b[i]!=0) { i=-1; break; }
    c-=dc;
    delete[] b;
    return c;
    }
```

- first ensure that the input numbers are sorted descending (`b[]` array)
- it is an leftover from older code you just need to have the largest num in `b[0]`
- then remove duplicate multiples (for example 8,4,2 ... use only 8)
- and at last use the sieve
- you do not actually need to store the sieve in memory
- instead just compute the sieve incrementally
- and remember only the the largest number multiples `c`
- if all the rest of the numbers are divisible you found the result

**[edit2] use of gcd**

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
int gcd(int a0,int a1)
    {
    int d,r,r0;
    if (a0<a1) { r=a0; a0=a1; a1=r; }
    // euklid a0/a1
    d=a0/a1;
    r=a0%a1; r0=r;
    if (!r) return a1;
    // a1/r0
    d=a1/r0;
    r=a1%r0;
    if (!r) return r0;
    a0=r0; a1=r;
    for (;;)
        {
        if (a0<a1) { r=a0; a0=a1; a1=r; }
        d=a0/a1;
        r=a0%a1;
        if (!r) return a1;
        a0=a1; a1=r;
        }
    return 0;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
int lcm(int *a,int N)                               // least common multiple of a[N]
        {
        int a0,a1,aa;
        if (N==0) return 0;
        if (N==1) return a[0];
        a0=a[0];
        if (N==2) a1=a[1]; else a1=lcm(a+1,N-1);
        aa=gcd(a0,a1);
        if (N==2) return (a0*a1)/aa;
        return (a1/aa)*a0;
        }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- this is much faster then sieves ...

Comment: How can this possibly be faster? OP's approach is O(n log W) where n is the number of elements and W is the maximum value. Your is something like O(W log W), which is much worse. Also what's the need for mul/div? You can avoid the overflows much more easily by dividing by the gcd before multiplying and by using 64-bit integers (i.e. `int64_t`).