# Return all least common multiples of a set of numbers within a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to create a function which produces a list of all the numbers from 1 through 300 that are divisible by both 6 and 10 by using a list comprhension. The expected output is below:

```
 ist_result = special_nums()
    list_result
[30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
```

I think that I might have to use the range function in a way but im not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?  3 thoughts: `range` by default starts at 0 and doesn't include the end of the range.  You can include a guard condition in list comprehensions: `[i for i in x if ...]`.  You can express "6 divides n" with `not n%6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expression will do (since 30 is 6 and 10's lowest common denominator):

```
[n for n in range(1, 301) if n % 30 == 0]
```

Comment: Note to readers: This (inefficiently) iterates through every element in the range when the stride can instead be pre-computed for better efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147539/4909087), define a function to compute the prime of 2 or more numbers:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm."""
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Return lowest common multiple."""
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)

def lcmm(*args):
    """Return lcm of args."""   
    return reduce(lcm, args)
```

Next, compute the lcm of your numbers and then iteratively emit numbers. Good thing is, if you know the lcm, you won't have to go over every number in the range.

```
from math import ceil

def get_multiples(start, end, *args):
   lcm = lcmm(*args)
   start = max(lcm, lcm * ceil(start / lcm))  # max(..., ...) in case start < lcm
   for i in range(start, end + 1, lcm):
       yield i
```

```
>>> list(get_multiples(1, 300, 6, 10))
[30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
```

As noted above, this is efficient since it doesn't iterate over every value in the supplied range, and efficiently scales to > 2 values:

```
>>> list(get_multiples(79, 400, 6, 10, 20))
[120, 180, 240, 300, 360]
```