# How to not return two different types from func?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following method:

```
async def check_for_pending_status(self, alert_id):
    alert_comments = await get_comments(alert_id)
    for comm in alert_comments:
        if comm['status'] == COMMENT_STATUS.PENDING.value:
            return True, comm.get('email')
    return False
```

That's how I use it:

```
is_pending_exists, email = await self.check_for_pending_status(comment.alert_id)
if is_pending_exists:
    comment['status'] = COMMENT_STATUS.PENDING
    if email is not None:
        comment['email'] = email
```

I'm new in python. I don't know is it good to return in one method `tuple` - `True, comm.get('email')` and just one value - `False`.

Is there any way to improve algorithm and rewrite it in the more pythonic way (I mean rewrite loop iteration)?

Comment: Why not just `return comm.get("email")` or `return None`? The `True/False` is kinda redundant. Or can `comm.get("email")` be `None`? (From the second `if` it seems like it can)

Comment: @tobias_k yes, I can `return comm.get("email")`. Could you write it as the answer so I can accept this?

Comment: Good practice is to **always return the same type from a function** (in all exit paths).  In this case, you would want to always return a tuple consisting of a `(bool, email)` pair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice in python for return value on error vs. success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630706/best-practice-in-python-for-return-value-on-error-vs-success)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that `comm.get('email')` can *not* be `None` itself, you could just return the e-mail of the pending comment, if any, or `None` otherwise.

```
async def check_for_pending_status(self, alert_id):
    alert_comments = await get_comments(alert_id)
    for comm in alert_comments:
        if comm['status'] == COMMENT_STATUS.PENDING.value:
            return comm.get('email')
    return None
```

And then check like this:

```
pending_email = await self.check_for_pending_status(comment.alert_id)
if pending_email is not None:
    comment['status'] = COMMENT_STATUS.PENDING
    comment['email'] = email
```

You could also rewrite this using `next`, but whether that's better might be a matter of taste:

```
async def check_for_pending_status(self, alert_id):
    alert_comments = await get_comments(alert_id)
    return next((comm.get('email') for comm in alert_comments 
                 if comm['status'] == COMMENT_STATUS.PENDING.value),
                None)
```

Comment: `comm.get('email')` can return None

Comment: @petrush Well, that's why I asked in the comment before posting this answer... :-/

Comment: @petrush If the e-mail _can_ be `None` you really should not use this, as you then will not be able to distinguish from a pending comment with none-email and a non-pending comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to return a `tuple` from a method.

If you don't like the fact you return only `False` you can always return `False, None`

Comment: I also though of this, but I would not say "if you don't like the fact ...". OP's original code simply would not work with result unpacking (`is_pending_exists, email = await self.check_for...`)