# Making return type of python optional

Tags: python-3.x

In JVM languages there is a data type called Optional which says value can be Null/None. By using the data type of a function as Option(for example Option(Int)). Calling statement of function can take action.

How does one implement a similar approach in Python.
I want to create a function and the return value of function should tell me 
1. Function was successful so I have a value returned.
2. Function was not successful and so there is nothing to return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice in python for return value on error vs. success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630706/best-practice-in-python-for-return-value-on-error-vs-success)

Comment: tl;dr use exceptions.

Comment: @mkrieger,  Thanks for your comment. At some cases I don't want the calling function to cause an exception. Especially when I create a common library that will be used by batch processing application. Then I want the call site to handle the error(or some time a particular unexpected behavior that doesn't warrant an exception) and take action instead of failing a long running batch process.

Comment: There's not a lot of difference between handling an exception at the call site, or checking a return value at the call site. The only difference is that exceptions force you to handle them, while return values can be ignored, so it seems you want exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

I also wanted to tackle this problem and made a library called [optional.py](https://github.com/cbefus/optional.py) to do so.  It can be installed using `pip install optional.py`.  It is fully test covered and supports python2 and python3.  Would love some feedback, suggestions, contributions.

To address the concerns of the other answer, and to head off any haters, yes, raising exceptions is more idiomatic of python, however it leads to ambiguity between exceptions for control-flow and exceptions for actual exceptional reasons.

There are large discussions about preventing defensive programming which mask the core logic of an application and smart people on both sides of the conversation.  My personal preference is towards using optionals and so I provided the library to support that preference.  Doing it with exceptions (or returning `None`) are acceptable alternatives, just not my preference.

Answer (score 1):

To your original question: Raise an exception instead of returning `None`. This is an idiom in Python and therefore well understood by users. For example

```
def get_surname(name):
    if name == "Monty":
        return "Python"
    else:
        raise KeyError(name)
```

You'll see this usage pattern a lot in Python:

```
try:
    print(get_surname("foo"))
except KeyError:
    print("Oops, no 'foo' found")
```

Based on your feedback, it also seemed like you wanted to make sure that certain return values are actually used. This is quite tricky, and I don't think there is an elegant way to enforce this in Python, but I'll give it a try.

First, we'll put the return value in a property so we can track if it has indeed been read.

```
class Result(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self.used = False

    @property
    def value(self):
        self.used = True # value was read
        return self._value
```

Secondly, we require that the `Result` object must be retrieved in a `with`-block. When the block is exited (`__exit__`), we check if the value has been read. To handle cases where a user doesn't use the `with`-statement, we also check that the value has been read when it is being garbage collected (`__del__`). An exception there will be converted into a warning. I usually shy away from `__del__` though.

```
class RequireUsage(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._result = Result(value)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._result

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if type is None: # No exception raised
            if not self._result.used:
                raise RuntimeError("Result was unused")

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._result.used:
            raise RuntimeError("Result was unused (gc)")
```

To use this system, simply wrap the return value in `RequireUsage` like so:

```
def div2(n):
    return RequireUsage(n/2)
```

To use such functions, wrap them in a block and extract the `value`:

```
with div2(10) as result:
    print(result.value)
```

If you don't invoke `result.value` anywhere, you will now get an exception:

```
with div2(10) as result:
    pass # exception will be thrown
```

Likewise, if you just call `div2` without `with` at all, you will also get an exception:

```
div2(10) # will also raise an exception
```

I wouldn't particularly recommend this exact approach in real programs, because I feel it makes usage more difficult while adding little. Also, there are still edge-cases that aren't covered, like if you simply do `res = div2(10)`, because a held reference prevents `__del__` from being invoked.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using the None option to implement this. But some times I forget to handle the None condition at call site. This in turn some times causes run time error.  I was wondering if there is some way to enforce handling None case check at call site to avoid run time errors. JVM languages being compiled languages enforces this when I use Option as return type. Something similar for Python?

Comment: Python cannot do static typechecking, so it's up to you not to forget to handle `None`.

Comment: @Abin Raising an exception if there is no meaningful result forces you to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @Abin: I have heavily edited this answer, and now it seems to be a bit beside the point. In your original case, I'd just raise an exception instead of returning None, because (as mkrieger1 says) it requires users to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to return either `()` or `(<type>,)` (`int` in your case). You could then come up with some helper functions like this one:

```py
def get_or_else(option: tuple, default):
  if option:
    return option[0]
  else:
    return default
```

One benefit of this approach is that you don't need to depend on a third-party library to implement this. As a counterpart, you basically have to make your own little library.