# Is there a way to know if a list of elements is on a larger list without using 'in' keyword?

Tags: python

I want to do this. I have two python lists, one larger than the other and I want to know is there is a way to check if the elements of the smaller list are in the big list in the exact same order for example:

```
small_list = [4,2,5]
big_list = [1,2,5,7,2,4,2,5,67,8,5,13,45]
```

I tried using the *in* keyword but It did not worked :'(

Comment: the in keyword will only tell you if small_list, is an element of big_list...

big_list = [1,2,5,7,2,small_list,4,2,5,67,8,5,13,45]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def in_list(small, big):
    l_sml = len(small)
    l_big = len(big)
    return any((big[i:i+l_sml]==small for i in xrange(l_big-l_sml+1)))

print in_list([4,2,1], [1,2,3,4,2,1,0,5]) # True
print in_list([1,2,3], [1,2,4])           # False
```

Comment: Maybe better to replace the `if True in` with the `any()` function?

Comment: Splendid suggestion, thanks ! (I edited the answer accordingly). 'any' is one of those functions I tend to always forget about...

Comment: And please make it 'return any(...)'. any() already returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, maybe it's overkill, but you can use the SequenceMatcher class from difflib:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher 
small_list = [4,2,5]
big_list = [1,2,5,7,2,4,2,5,67,8,5,13,45]
print SequenceMatcher(None, small_list, big_list).get_matching_blocks()
```

[difflib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 3):

Rather non-optimized, demonstrates the general strategy simply:

```
tuple(small_list) in zip(big_list[:], big_list[1:], big_list[2:])
```

The funky zip thing does this:

```
>>> zip(big_list[:], big_list[1:], big_list[2:])
[(1, 2, 5), (2, 5, 7), (5, 7, 2), (7, 2, 4), (2, 4, 2), (4, 2, 5), (2, 5, 67), (5, 67, 8), (67, 8, 5), (8, 5, 13), (5, 13, 45)]
```

A more optimized version:

```
from itertools import izip, islice
tuple(small_list) in izip(big_list, islice(big_list, 1, None), islice(big_list, 2, None))
```

To handle small_list length of any size:

```
from itertools import izip, islice
tuple(small_list) in izip(*(islice(big_list, i, None) for i in xrange(len(small_list))))
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Not very general, but works ok if the small list is ALWAYS VERY SMALL.

Comment: generalizing it for different length of the small list is straightforward

Comment: Isn't this solution optimal even if small_list is not very small?

Comment: the optimized versions using itertool's generator functions should be perfectly OK

Answer (score 2):

This problem is trickier than it seems.  Unless I'm mistaken, it's a special case of the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

For the general case (arbitrarily large lists), I would use some kind of [finite state automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), akin to a regular expression.  I believe the result could then be calculated in O(mn) time.

Comment: You are mistaken. It's the same as finding if a substring T in S, which is doable in linear time.

Comment: @Daniel: It's the same as finding a substring, true. However IIRC that is worst case O(mn) e.g. T = "a" * 8 + "b"; S = "a" * 9 * 100 when done with brute force algorithms as presented in answers here.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `small_list in big_list` checks whether an element in big_list is equal to small_list.  What you want to do instead is see if a slice of big_list is the same as small_list.

```
def isSubList(slice, L):
    n = len(slice)
    for i in range(0, len(L) - n):
        if slice == L[i:i+n]:
            return True
    return False

isSubList(small_list, big_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Leaving the answer here but I failed to note the requirement that they be in the same order. This does not meet that requirement**

Quick and dirty answer. Based it off of the answer for [Python - Intersection of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

```
small_list == filter( lambda x: x in big_list, small_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know a reasonable bound of your numbers, you can convert them to a Python type whose 'in' operator does this automatically. The two I know are `str` and `unicode`.

Then you ask the strings if the smaller is in the larger, this does a substring comparison:

```
>>> small_list = [4,2,5]
>>> big_list = [1,2,5,7,2,4,2,5,67,8,5,13,45]
>>>
>>> def encode(lst):
      return u"".join(unichr(c) for c in lst)

>>> encode(small_list) in encode(big_list)
True
```

(You can "encode" to `str` if all numbers are in `0 <= x <= 255`, you can "encode" to `unicode` if all are in `0 <= x <= sys.maxunicode` ).

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in operator doing that particular comparison. I suggest a list comprehension or a quick for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sets

```
from sets import Set
small_set = set(small_list)
big_set = set(big_list)
small_set <= big_set
```

<= is the subset operator

Comment: oops, also missed the same order part of the question so doesn't answer the original question, but may be of use to someone looking to solve similar problems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the "in" keyword to do what you want, you can override **contains** using one of the solutions mentioned in the answers here:

```
class mylist(list):
    def __contains__(self, lst):
        return ':'.join(map(str, lst)) in ':'.join(map(str, self))

small_list = mylist([4,2,5])
big_list = mylist([1,2,5,7,2,4,2,5,67,8,5,13,45])

print small_list in big_list
```

Edit: Addresses Jeffrey's comment.

Comment: This won't work for two digit numbers, you'd return true for:

big_list = [4,2,53]

If you really wanted to take this tortured approach and you know your algorithm only needs to work with integers less than max_unicode, see kaizer.se's answer.

Comment: You can use a delimeter like ":" to fix this.